# Segmentation fault in C

Tags: c

```
void main() {
    int num;
    num = 1;
    num++;
    num = num + 9;
    printf('%u',num);
}
```

What is wrong with this? It says segmentation fault.
Written in C.

Comment: also use `int main(int argc, char **argv)`!

Comment: Although in this case it is fairly obvious which line the error is on, please include this info explicitly in your future posts - it makes everyone's life easier (including your own).

Comment: It's a good idea to look at the output of your compiler. I am sure it did warn you already about the printf().

Answer (score 8):

`'%u'` should be `"%u"` (double quotes). C is not SQL, and `'%u'` is considered a [multicharacter literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal).

And as Erik said, `%d` is better in your case.

Comment: @Ian - If this solved your issue, you should mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

`printf("%d")` - printf takes a C string not a character. `%d` is the correct format specifier for an integer.

Answer (score 3):

That '%u' ( a multi-character char constant) should be "%u" (a char array). The char constant is being misinterpreted as a pointer to random memory.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you would have gotten an error from passing the wrong type (`int` instead of `const char *`) as the first argument of `printf`, except that you forgot to `#include <stdio.h>` or prototype `printf` yourself. And since `printf` is a variadic function, this results in UB too.