# VC++ Project, want to compile within another IDE but something is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compilation

I am fairly new to C++.
I want to write plugins for an application called [Cinema 4D](http://www.maxon.net/en/home.html).
Maxon, the maker of C4D, provides an API for doing this. The header-files are located in a special folder.

The "cinema4dskd" is a Visual Studio project containing sample plugins. Within this project there is another subproject called **_api** .

[image]

*The popupwindow is the "Project dependencies" dialog.*

The **_api** sub project seems to be a link to a file that is present on my localdrive but it is not within the cinema4dsdk.vcproj.
All files within the **_api** project are located in a folder in the Cinema 4D installation path also called **_api**.
It is full of header and .cpp files.
This is basically what I need to compile plugins for Cinema 4D, including "c4d.h" in my source code.
But this is where the problems start.

I'm trying to compile a plugin within Code::Blocks, I have added all paths to "c4d.h", etc. But every compiler (gcc, and even msvc !) tell me thousands of warnings about:

**C:\Programs\MAXON\Cinema 4D R12\resource\_api\ge_prepass.h |2668|warning: multi-character character constant|**

And finally an error that `C4DGLuint` isn't declared. Why does it work in VC++ but not with any other compiler ? I must have missed something, but I really don't know what.

I don't think I am allowed to share this project, as the **_api** is owned by Maxon GmbH, but if you really need it I beg you to download the Cinema 4D Demo version where the *cinema4dskd* project is included.

Tell me if you need any further information, I hope you have an idea what may be missing. Why the heck can VC++ compile the Plugins right, but I can't using the command-line or any other IDE ?

Thank you very much.
Niklas

**Updates:**

Example of *multicharacter constant*  error:

> C:\Users\niklas\Documents\CodeBlocks\Cinema4D\_api\src\gui.h|690|warning: multi-character character constant|
>   C:\Users\niklas\Documents\CodeBlocks\Cinema4D\_api\src\gui.h|693|warning: multi-character character constant|

```
690: BFM_SETVIEWPORTORIGIN  = 'cORG',
691:    BFM_SETVIEWPORTORIGIN_X=1,
692:    BFM_SETVIEWPORTORIGIN_Y=2,
693: BFM_SETVIEWPORTSIZE    = 'cSIZ',
```

Comment: Where is C4DGLuint declared? Are you including that header? As for the warnings, can you paste the exact line?

Comment: Ah, good one, I thought all headers are included in `c4d.h`, but `c4d_gl.h` isn't. If I add it to `operatingssystem.h`(where the error occures) it works, but another comes up (Also, I shouldn't modify theese files I think, they work in VC++ as well). `C4DOS is not declared in this scope.`. I see, C4DOS is externed in *operatingsystem.h*: `extern OperatingSystem C4DOS;`, but in the file where the error occures, *operatingsystem.h*  is included.

Comment: Btw, I have copied `_api` to Code::Blocks now and try to build it (it is setup as a .lib in VC++, however, but I couldn't see where it is linkd into the cinema4dskd ?) so I can just test it when I may need to modify the files ^^ Man very hard to explain, especially as I'm so new to compilation stuff.

Comment: "As for the warnings", I'll do, see update.

Comment: For above, `OperatingSystem` is a struct declared some lines above, it has pointers to other parts of the C4D api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'cORG'
```

is a so-called multi character literal. Its value does not fit into a `char` variable, you will need an 'int' to hold it, and according to this post

[C++ multicharacter literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal)

it is compiler-specific how this thing is interpreted. Seems the other compiler you have tested does not support those kind of literals.

Comment: Using Msvc with CodeBlocks gives the same warnings, but not in visual studio. But maybe they are suppressed there ?