# char to int conversion - what's happening here?

Tags: c++, char, int, type-conversion

I want to convert a `char` value to an `int`. I am playing with following code snippets:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a = 'A';
    int i = (int)a;
    //cout<<i<<endl; OUTPUT is 65 (True)

    char b = '18';
    int j = b;
    //cout<<j<<endl; OUTPUT is 56 (HOW?)

    char c = 18;
    int k = c;
    //cout<<c<<endl; OUTPUT is empty
    //cout<<k<<endl; OUTPUT is 18 (Is this a valid conversion?)

    return 0;
}
```

I want the third conversion, and I got correct output i.e `18`. But is this a valid conversion? Can anyone please explain the above outputs and their strategies?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal

Comment: For the last, you might want to check an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). The casting itself (you *type cast*, not converse) is okay though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char a = 'A';
int i = (int)a;
```

The cast is unnecessary. Assigning or initializing an object of a numeric type to a value of any other numeric type causes an implicit conversion.

The value stored in `i` is whatever value your implementation uses to represent the character `'A'`. On almost all systems these days (except some IBM mainframes and maybe a few others), that value is going to be `65`.

```
char b = '18';
int j = b;
```

A character literal with more than one character is of type `int` and has an implementation-defined value. It's likely that the value will be `'1'<<8+'8'`, and that the conversion from `char` to `int` drop the high-order bits, leaving `'8'` or `56`. But multi-character literals are something to be avoided. (This doesn't apply to escape sequences like `'\n'`; though there are two characters between the single quotes, it represents a single character value.)

```
char c = 18;
int k = c;
```

`char` is an integer type; it can easily hold the integer value `18`. Converting that value to `int` just preserves the value. So both `c` and `k` are integer variables whose valie is `18`. Printing `k` using

```
std::cout << k << "\n";
```

will print `18`, but printing `c` using:

```
std::cout << c << "\n";
```

will print a non-printable control character (it happens to be Control-R).

Answer (score 1):

```
char b = '18';
int j = b;
```

b, in this case a char of '18' doesn't have a very consistent meaning, and has implementation-dependent behaviour. In your case it appears to get translated to ascii value 56 (equivalent to what you would get from char b = '8').

```
char c = 18;
int k = c;
```

c holds character value 18, and it's perfectly valid to convert to an int. However, it might not display very much if you display as a character. It's a non-printing control character.

Comment: Thanks if _c holds character value 18_ outputting it returns empty, why?

Comment: No, `'18'` is of type `int` and has an implementation-defined value. That value is converted from `int` to `char`, likely losing information.

Comment: so the later from `char` to `int` will not return in losing information? though it is outputting the correct value..

Comment: Trying to print ascii value 18 to the screen won't do very much. If you look up in a ascii table, you'll see why.