# An awful lot of compiler errors

Tags: c++, syntax

Alright, so I'm using C++ Bloodshed to do a program for my college assignment, and there are a ton of errors that I keep getting, such as
'syntax error before ')' token', 'syntax error before 'else', and 'syntax error at end of input'.
Here is the code, if you can help me out I would really appreciate it.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int points=0; //this is a global variable. it's made of variables and planets.
string studentID;
string units[10]; //global array of ten game matches in total.
char grades[10]; //these are the global medals that are awarded.

void intro();
void load_units(); //this, the above and the below are all prototypes; defines what the function is.
void award_grades();
void award_points();
void set_units();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    intro();
    load_units();
    award_grades();
    award_points();
    cout<<"You have achieved..."<<points<<endl;
    set_units();

    system("PAUSED!!!!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void intro()
{
     cout<<"Welcome to the Grading System for BTEC!"<<endl;
     cout<<"This app will determine your grades, with either Pass, Merit, or Distinction." <<endl;
     cout<<"Please enter your name to continue."<<endl;
     cin>>studentID;
     }
     void load_points()
     {
          units[0]="NOCN";
          units[1]="Animation";
          units[2]="Game Designing";
          units[3]="OSS";
          units[4]="HCI";
          units[5]="Digital Art";
          units[6]="SAD";
          units[7]="Project Planning";
          units[8]="Procedural Programming";
          units[9]="Database Design";
          }

          void award_grades()
          {
               int index; //This is a local variable. It more or less allows for a global variable's value to be retained.
             for (index=0; index<10; index=index+1)
             {
{
             cout<<"What grade did you get for the"<<units[index]<<"unit?"<<endl;
             cin>>grades[index];
             }
             void award_points();
                  for (index=0, index<10, index=index+1)
                      switch (grades[index]);
                      {
                             case'distinction':
                                        points=points +3; //Code for the event points. The following are also event codes...
                             break;
                             case'merit':
                                          points=points +2;
                             break;
                             case'pass':
                                          points=points +1;
                             break;
                             case'd':
                                          points=points +3;
                             break;
                             case'm':
                                          points=points +2;
                             break;
                             case'p':
                                          points=points +1;
                             break;
                             }
                      }
                  }
void set_units()
{
     if(points>13)
     {// if the points are more than 13 then...
                  cout<<studentID + "Well done! You have a distinction!"<<endl;
                  }
                  {
                               else if(points<8);//otherwise, if points are more than 8 but below more than 13, then...
                                   cout<<studentID+"Congratulations, you have a merit!"<<endl;
                                   }
                                   {
                                                else if(points<3); //If the points are more than 3 but not more than 8 then...
                                                    cout<<studentID+"You have a pass! Try to keep it up and get a higher grade."<<endl;
                                                    }
                                                    {
     else; //if none of these conditions are met, then...
         {
     cout<<studentID + "Your studentID is not enlisted. Either enrol, or re-enter your name correctly. Remember, it's case-sensitive."<<endl;
     }
```

Comment: Check semicolons. **Count braces**. But first of all fix the indentation.

Comment: FYI syntax for a for loop goes like this:
`for (int i=0; i<n; i++)`. **Semicolons**. And there there ain't a semicolon after `switch`.

Comment: First off, expressions inside a `for` statement are separated with `;`, not `,`. Then you've got a bunch of semicolons where there shouldn't be. Then things like `'bananas'`, they don't do what you think they do (see [multi character literals.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal)). Then... I give up.

Comment: Same goes for your `set_units()` function. Just by looking at it you can see that there is something wrong with those if-then statements. You have 6 opening braces and only 4 closing ones.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fixing multiple syntax errors.

Comment: Great title. Summarizes my life.

Comment: @jogojapan You should go out more, then :)

Comment: OMG! Who taught you this kind of C++??!

Comment: And get a better compiler ASAP. GCC/Clang for Linux and MSVC for Windows are the main ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the error message points you to this line

```
for (index=0, index<10, index=index+1)
```

You've written `,` where you meant `;`

Once you've fixed that, the first error message will probably point you at or near

```
switch (grades[index]);
```

where you've got a rogue `;`

Then it will point you at the scrambled `if...else` formatting in `set_units`, which should look something like

```
if (...) {
   ...
} else if (...) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: just an update: i've tried doing the extra work, and then the errors sort of multiplied - errors like "in function 'void award_grades()'", "in function 'void set_units()'", and the syntax errors for the else statements are still there.

Comment: @ProfessorLemur: If the syntax errors for the `else` statements are still there, then the syntax is still wrong. Do they look like my example, with no extra `{`, `}`, or `;` anywhere?

Comment: I can safely say that the syntax errors for else are now gone; now there are just the "in function" errors and the syntax error at end of input.

Comment: @ProfessorLemur: "In function" isn't itself an error - it's telling you where to look for the following error or warning. The remaining warnings in `award_grades` are because you're not sure whether `grades[index]` should be a single character like `'d'`, or a string like `"distinction"`. You'll need to check what the input is supposed to be (single characters only, or whole words), and fix the logic accordingly. (You can use `switch` on a single character, but you'll need `if...else` to select code based on a string's value).

Comment: This leaves just the end of input error. I tried "end", }, and a ;, but nothing seems to leave it. Any ideas? Thanks so much for your help, by the way.

Comment: @ProfessorLemur: Tidy up the indentation so that you can see which block(s) are missing `}` at the end. Then add the missing `}` in the right place.

Comment: I finally done this; I ended up with linker errors to undefined references to 'load_units()' and 'award_points()'. Other than that, I'm all clear. Thanks, you are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

First, your commas should be semi-colons:

```
for (index=0; index<10; index=index+1)
```

Second, you have a semi-colon after your `switch`:

```
switch (grades[index])
```

Third, you cannot use a `switch` for a `string`, let alone a multi-character `char`. It will convert it to a large-ass number, which is probably not what you want. Instead you need to refactor it to if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Linker errors are occuring because you have defined prototypes of functions `load_units` and `award_points` :-)
If you define bodies of these functions you will not get the errors.
BTW this look just like my assignemnt on my first year in Computer Games Development :-)
Good luck.

Comment: managed to fix this by just adding a couple of voids at the end of input; thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @ProfessorLemur no worries :-)