# Preprocessor: convert macro parameter to multicharacter literal

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

In a nutshell:

It's possible to convert macro parameter to character string literal (that contains the spelling of the preprocessing token sequence for the corresponding
argument, regarding to 16.3.2, n3797) with # operator. Is there a way, some trick, maybe, to convert macro parameter to multibyte character ?
So, for example, I will have some macro TO_CHAR(WHATEWER) and TO_CHAR(CONSTANT) will give me 'CONSTANT' multibyte character ?

I need this to work with `boost::mpl::string`. More precisely, I think so:

I have a lot of constants and I work with them with `boost::mpl::vector` (`boost::mpl::vector_c`). Now, I need to print out the name of constant after some work with this constant. Pseudo-pseudo code:

```
struct Temp
{
    template<typename Value>
    operator()(Value)
    {
        // ...
        std::cout << "The value of " << @Value::value Name << " is " << Value::value;
    };
};
typedef boost::mpl::vector_c<int, MY_CONST1, MY_CONST2> Constants;
boost::mpl::for_each<Constants>(Temp());
```

The output must be something like this:

```
The value of MY_CONST1 is 1
The value of MY_CONST2 is 2
```

I don't want to make some runtime array with a lot of typing:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector_c<int, MY_CONST1, MY_CONST2> Constants;
const char* constant_names[] = { "MY_CONST1", "MY_CONST2" };
// Work with this stuff
```

What I want to have is something like this:

```
#define MAP_CONST(CONST) boost::mpl::pair<boost::mpl::int_<CONST>, (boost::mpl::string maybe here) #CONST>

typedef boost::mpl::vector<MAP_CONST(MY_CONST1), MAP_CONST(MY_CONST2)> Constants;
// Work with @Constants
```

Btw, I can't use constexp or new standard in general - I have C++03 compiler.

Thanks

**UPD:** Sorry for my mismatch - I mean not multibyte character, but "multicharacter literal" (regarding standard - 2.14.3, n3797). Somrthing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal)

Comment: Why are you using multicharacter literals? You realize, printing out a multicharacter literal like `'MY_CONST1'` is not, in general, going to produce `MY_CONST1` as output.

Comment: @Brian, yes, but this will do boost::mpl::c_str with boost::mpl::string (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/string.html)

Comment: @user2451677 _'"multicharacter literal" (regarding standard - 2.14.3, n3797). Somrthing like this'_ That's a completely different thing vs. _"multibyte character"_ you are completely seem to be confused about this. Multicharacter literals are implementation defined and dependent, don't use them. It's not portable by means of standards. What else did you miss from that link you gave?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I already told that that was my mistake. I just want to work with boost::mpl::string. The only way to do this is to use multicharacter literal. The link that I gave is just to show what is multicharacter literal. What other cavils to my mistake and bad example ?

Comment: @user2451677 You're still asking for _"Is there a way, some trick, maybe, to convert macro parameter to multibyte character ?"_ :P ...

Comment: @user2451677 Is it true that the *only* way to use `boost::mpl::string` is to use multicharacter literals? Seems to me it would accept a sequence of single-character literals just as well.

Comment: @Brian, yes, so here is another question: is there a way to represent MY_CONST as a sequence of single-character literals ? :P