# why this loop is running infinite times in c?

Tags: c, for-loop, char

I was just experimenting a code in C programming. and came to know a strange behavior.
Well... Since i am not an expert on C, so i don't know whether its strange or normal.

Basically my question is all about the difference between the following two lines of code:-

```
char a = 'h'; // here variable a is not an array of "char"
```

and

```
char a = 'hi'; //here variable a is not an array of "char" as well (i don't know if compiler assumes it as an array or not but , at least i didn't declared it that way )
```

I used the following codes

first:-

```
char a =0;
for(;a<'hi';a++)
{
    printf("%d= hello world \n",a);
}
```

second:-

```
char a;
for(a='h';a<'hi';a++)
{
    printf("%d= hello world \n",a);
}
```

both of the above mentioned loops keep running forever,

Can somebody tell me why so ?

I might be missing a very basic concept of programing. please help me guys

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3960954/440558

Comment: Explain how did you wait for an infinitely long time :-)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch :- ha ha.. well first time it was 3000 and next i waited for quite long. (22854)

Comment: `'hi'` is wrong, 2 chars means it's a string, which requires double quotes, and `"hi"` decays into a pointer. The correct declaration would be `const char * a = "hi";` or `char a[] = "hi"`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : well... compiler didn't gave me an error with this code.

Comment: BTW if you compiled with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) the compiler would have warned you (and then you can use the `gdb` debugger)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : yes there were warnings but what i am asking is the reason behind those warnings. what is wrong here?

Comment: `char a = 'hi';` is not possible -- you can only store a single char in a `char`!

Comment: Trust the compiler. If it warns you your code is wrong. And read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] (@BasileStarynkevitch no need for -Wall here)

Comment: Multichar constants are implementation-defined. Different compilers (or build platform targets) can produce different value. You generally cannot rely on that, and most compilers warns you about it. You always can avoid using them, so just don't. `'foo'` and `"foo"` are completely different things.

Comment: @Maxime: for a newbie `-Wall -Wextra` is always useful

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : well .. I was using Xcode in MAC OS X so..didn't know how to use "-Wall -Wextra"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch they are always useful, not only for newbies. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because `'hi'` has type `int` not a `char`. It also resolves to value 26729. But loop variable most likely (assuming `char` is 1-byte type and byte has 8 bits) is limited by 127 and after that overflows.

Note that this:

```
char a =0;
char m = 'hi';
for(; a < m; a++)
{
    printf("%d= hello world \n",a);
}
```

will work because `'hi'` is will be coerced to char (105).

`'hi'` is a multi-character literal. It is not common practice in programming, it is "less known" C feature which became part of C99 standard. More information about them: http://zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/computers/languages/c_multi-char_const.html

Comment: Might be good to mention that this even has a proper name - a *multi-character literal*

Comment: how can i find value of 'hi'. or according to Mints97  any "multi-character literal"

Comment: The integer value of a multi-character literal looks dodgy to me, though: C99 => §6.4.4.4.10: _"The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), [...] is implementation-defined."_, so there is some possible undefined behavior at play here

Comment: @DemonSOCKET: it is implementation-defined. Some compilers combine the ASCII values of the symbols in a multi-character literal as Sergey explained, and some compilers simply take the last character of the literal. To figure out what the value is in your case, just output it to stdout as a number =)

Comment: In other words, *avoid them*. If you really want to combine two text characters, do so in a way you will know what the result is: `int a = ('h'<<8)+'i';`.

Answer (score 1):

In C (as opposed to C++, as cited in some comments), character literals, *always* have type `int`. It doesn't matter if it's an ordinary one-character literal, such as 'c', or a multi-character literal, such as 'hi'. It always has type `int`, which is required to hold at least 16 bit. A `char` holds exactly one byte.

When comparing integer values of different type, integer-promotion rules kick in and the integer value of smaller size gets promoted to the larger one.
That is why `a < 'hi'` can only be `1` ("true"). Even if promoted to type `int`, the variable `a` can never hold anything larger than `MAX_CHAR`. But the multi-character literal `'hi'` is an `int` with a larger value than that **in your complier's implementation**.

The reason that `a < m` can succeed is that when declaring `m`, you initialise it with `'hi'` which gets converted to type `char`, which indeed has a chance to compare not-less-than an other `char`.

Comment: stuff after 1st Paragraph .. gone completely over my head. :) I mean couldn't understand the integer-promotion rule. no offense.

Comment: @DemonSOCKET then you should read more about it. Or it will hurt later.

Comment: @DemonSOCKET: What exactly was unclear about the description? Did you check the standard?