# How can I debug this basic OR program?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C programming.

I have written a program which is not functioning due to its 'OR' functionality. Here is a working code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* englishTest = 'yup';

    if ( (englishTest == 'yup') || (englishTest == 'yep') || (englishTest == 'yas') || (englishTest == 'yah') )
    {
        printf("You may pass \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You shall not pass \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char englishTest = 'yup';`...and your compiler did not scream?

Comment: You're comparing multi-character literals, not the strings. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189073/why-this-loop-is-running-infinite-times-in-c

Comment: The syntax is all wrong. Try `char englishTest[] = "yup";` etc. followed by `strcmp(englishTest, "yup") == 0` etc. Don't forget to `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: @WeatherVane that probably explains it. I haven't learnt about strcmp yet. Thanks.

Comment: @SouravGhosh hahaha my compiler has seen worse :P

Comment: @SouravGhosh: `-Wconversion` is not part of the standard warnings, iirc not even for `-Wextra`

Comment: @MythicCocoa: Enable all recommended warings and pay heed to them!

Comment: @RushatRai Please dont add stuff to the title of the question that has no impact on it. Even if it was a bad question, adding needless text to the title just makes it worse.

Comment: @JoshMein oh, okay, cool. I'll change it back. Edit: nvm, you did it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supposed to be `C`, not a scripting language.

There are two problems in this code:

```
char englishTest = 'yup';
```

`englishTest` is declared as [`char`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type) which in `C` is an integer type. It can hold only one character but you attempt to store three characters in it.

What you probably meant is:

```
char englishTest[] = "yup";
```

Please note the square brackets that denote an [array (of chars)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array). The array size can be optionally specified between the brackets. It is not specified here and the compiler uses the smallest value that can hold the string used for [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) (`"yup"`). This smallest value is `4`: there are `3` characters in `"yup"` but [`C` strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) are terminated with [the `NULL` character (`'\0'`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

The second issue in your code is the comparison of strings. The strings are not primitive types in `C`. They are arrays of characters. Directly comparing two strings using the [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison) doesn't produce the result you expect. It compares the addresses in memory where the two strings are stored, not their characters.

The `C` standard library provides several functions to compare two strings. The most straightforward [string comparison function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) is [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). It returns `0` if the two strings are identical, a negative value if the first string comes before the second string in the [dictionary order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) or a negative value otherwise.

Your comparison code should be (note the `C` strings are enclosed in double quotes `""`):

```
if (strcmp(englishTest, "yup") == 0 || strcmp(englishTest, "yep") == 0 ||
    strcmp(englishTest, "yas") == 0 || strcmp(englishTest, "yah") == 0)
```

P.S. The OR operators (`||`) do not break anything here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :) When I tried- char englishTest[ ] = 'yup' then codeblocks told me "error: invalid initializer". When I tried- char* englishTest = 'yup' it worked. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @MythicCocoa the compiler will have issued you warnings for `'yup'` - please take note of them.

Comment: @WeatherVane in fact, it did. I didn't think much of these warnings if the code worked. I've learned my lesson :)

Comment: @MythicCocoa "it works" is no proof, perhaps lucky, That luck can run out at the very moment you demo the project to a client.