# replace char with string

Tags: c, string

I need to replace some chars with multiple chars (a string), but I got stuck. This code works for replacing one char with another, but if the replacement are multiple chars, the output messes up.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
char input[50];
char output[150];
int i;
printf("Enter your text: ");
fgets(input, 50 , stdin);

for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++){
    switch (input[i]){
        case 'a': output[i]= '4'; break;
        case 'd': output[i]= '|)';break;
        case 'e': output[i]= '3'; break;
        case 'f': output[i]= '|='; break;
        case 'u': output[i]= '|_|'; break;
        case 'w': output[i]= '\|/'; break;
        /* REST OF THE ALPHABET 
        INTENTIONALLY SUPPRESSED*/
    }
}
printf("Your new text is: %s", output);
return 0;
```

As suggested by dasblinkenlight, I set another index for the output, That worked pretty fine, but I getting two additional chars at the end of the output text... where does those chars come from?

This is an example:

Enter your text: afedef
Your new text is: 4|=3|)3|=■(

Comment: let's say a string is a row of watermallons wrapped with boxes. if you want to pull out a watermellon and replace it with a different one, there is no problem. but if you want one watermellon to be replaced with 3, you need to put extra 2 boxes each time . in our example , a byte is the box and the character is the watermellon

Comment: No need to use fruits. I understood that from the examples I saw.
So, I tried adding "spaces" to the output index, but that did't work.

Comment: Please *do not attempt* to stuff your code into the humble comment field. Just [edit] your post and add relevant information to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can't copy strings with `=` operator. 
2) String literal in c is surrounded with double quotes 
3) Special characters like backslash ('\') in string literals have a special meaning and should be escaped.
4) In order to do what you intend you will need:
 a) Additional counter to track the position in the `output` string, where the next string will be written 
 b) use of `strcpy/strncpy` instead of assignment operator `=` ,  such that each line in the `switch statement will look similar to this:

```
case 'f': strcpy(&output[j], "|="); j+=2; break;
```

Here `j` is the second counter incremented by the number of characters written to `output`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

- you are using `i` to iterate the output array. The size of the input array and output array are different. It may happen (e.g. in the case of `f`) that the index for the input array needs to be incremented by 1, whereas the index for the output array **should** be incremented by 2 or 3.
- you can't assign multiple chars to a single char slot in an array. For instance, `case 'f': output[i]= '|='; break;` is incorrect.

To solve the problem you should use another variable and increment it with the number of characters added. For example:

```
int j = 0;
...
  case 'e': 
   output[j++]= '3'; 
   break;
  case 'f': 
   output[j++]= '|'; 
   output[j++]= '='; 
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char *p = input, *q = output;

do    
{
    switch ( *p )
    {
        case '\0': *q = *p; break;
        case 'a': *q++ = '4'; break;
        case 'd': strcpy( q, "|)" ); q += 2; break;
        case 'e': *q++ = '3'; break;
        case 'f': strcpy( q, "|=" ); q += 2; break;
        case 'u': strcpy( q, "|_|" ); q += 3; break;
        case 'w': strcpy( q, "\|/" ); q += 3; break;
        /* REST OF THE ALPHABET 
        INTENTIONALLY SUPPRESSED*/
    }
} while ( *p++ );
```

Or instead of using `strcpy` you can assign each caharcter one after another as for example

```
        case 'd': *q++ = '|'; *q++ = ')'; break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `strcat` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/):

```
char input[50];
char output[150];
int i;
printf("Enter your text: ");
fgets(input, 50 , stdin);
output[0] = 0; // null terminate before calling strcat.

for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    switch (input[i])
    {
        case 'a': strcat(output, "4"); break;
        case 'd': strcat(output, "|)"); break;
        //...
    }
}
printf("Your new text is: %s", output);
```

Also, multiple characters in single quotes in C++ is implementation defined ([C++ multicharacter literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal)), you'll probably want to avoid them. Also, be careful when using '\' in literals (as with your last case), it's probably not doing what you expect.