# How to retrieve numeric value from character data type in c program

Tags: c

I want to retrieve a numeric value from a character type variable.

```
char x = '10';
int y = 10;
printf("x + y = %d",(int)x+y);
```

I expect 20 as the result.

Comment: What have you tried? There are built in tools, but it is a great programming learning exercise to write your own string to numeric converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf("x + y = %d",(int)x+y);`

Casting `char` to int doesn't convert it to a number, but rather gives you the integer value corresponding to the character that it's representing (typically ASCII or something compatible, but the C standard doesn't specify that). Here you're using a [*multi character literal*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal) (normally anything enclosed in single quotes should be just one character), to make matters worse; this is implementation defined as well. If you want to store more than a single digit, you will need a string:

`const char* x = "10"`.

You can then convert it to an integer using [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) or [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/). `atoi` is easier to use, but provides no way of checking whether or not the string contains a valid number.

Example:

```
const char* x = "10"; int y = 10;
printf("x + y = %d", atoi(x) + y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
char x[] = "10"; int y = 10;
printf("x + y = %d",atoi(x)+y);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C library, use `atoi(char *x)`, secondly characters cannot hold 2 characters, for that you need an array or pointer. Here's the code that you may need:

```
int main(){
        char *c = "10";
        int i = atoi(c);
        int j = 10;
        printf("i + j=%d",(i + j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code..........

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char x=10;
    int y=10;
    clrscr();

    printf("%d",(x+y));
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for 0 to 9..

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    int v = c - '0';
    // safely use v
}
```

Comment: c-'0'  how does it works?