# Enum as input to constructor c++ eclipse

Tags: c++, input, constructor, enums

I have a project in which I need to get Enum as an input from the user and send it to a constructor.. I searched , didn't find something like this on this website,so here is my Class containing Enums, which compiles:

```
class Worker {
public:
string myGender;
enum workerType {DIRECTOR,  ACTOR, COPYWRITER, PRODUCER} myType;
Worker::Worker(workerType type,string gend)
{
myType = type;
myGender = gend;
}
```

this is the relevant method from my main class, from which i perform actions, and this one compiles as well:

```
void MovieIndustry::addWorker(Worker::workerType type, string gend)
{    
         workers.push_back(Worker(type, gend));
         break;
}
```

From my main I want to get an input like:
0, male

and to add a Worker instance with parameters
myType = DIRECTOR
myGender = male

I tried this, and it doesn't compile:

```
#include "MovieIndustry.h" //this is not the problem, works for other funcs
int main() {
MovieIndustry cinema;
int numForWorkertype;
string stringForGender;
cin >> numForWorkertype >> stringForGender;
cinema.addWorker(numForWorkertype ,stringForGender);
return 0;
}

serInterface.cpp:54:64: error: no matching function for call to  
‘MovieIndustry::addWorker(int&, std::string&)’
```

HELP..?

Comment: Regarding the values of that `gender` enumeration, [you need to read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal).

Comment: As for your problems, enumerations are always integers, no matter how you try to initialize them. You simply can't use a string in place of an enumeration.

Comment: ok I changed the gender, but how do i get the workerType from the user ? I still need to get it as an int ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numForWorkertype is int type. Cast to Worker::workerType.

```
cinema.addWorker( (Worker::workerType)numForWorkertype ,stringForGender);
```