# putchar('\\') returns single '\' - on windows using mingw

Tags: c

Going through K&R 'The C Programming Language' and on exercise 1-10 where you are asked to replace each tab, backspace, and backslash with two backslashes. I noticed that my console is returning only '\'

example of my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{

 int c;

 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {


  switch (c) {
      case '\t': putchar ('\\');  break;
      case ' ': putchar ('\\');  break;
      case '\\': putchar ('\\'); break;
      default:   putchar (c);
  }
 }

}
```

to fix it I have to put:

```
  switch (c) {
      case '\t': putchar ('\\'); putchar ('\\') break;
```

is this something to do with windows and character literals or am I missing something?  Just wondering if this is an indication that I need to do some reading on how programming in c is going to be different for me on windows (even using gcc compiler)

Comment: even as I type in two forward slashes into this question it's reduced to one after posting, now I'm really confused

Comment: I think you need to change your code with [mcve].

Comment: `'\\'` is just one backslash character.`'//'` is not a valid character.

Comment: edited to show full code

Comment: Why not just use `char c;`?

Comment: erip, was maintaining int as had to deal with value for EOF

Comment: @MartinZabel Yes it is, although the value is implementation defined and therefore not terribly useful, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal

Comment: @Steve Summit definitely backslash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're falling victim to what many in the regex business call [blackslash hell](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/backslash-hell/).

Because traditionally `\` is used to denote escape sequence, escaping it can (understandably) get a little confusing.

For every `\` that you want to print, you need to escape it with another `\`.

```
display -> write
----------------
  \     -> \\
  \\    -> \\\\
```

etc. ad nauseum

Unfortunately `\\\\` isn't a `char`, so you won't be able to use `putchar`, but you'll want 4 slashes. You can use `puts("\\\\")` or use your current approach with two `putchar('\\')`.

Comment: thank you for this, especially for taking the time to include a useful article