# Why does the statement “cout << '\\\\';” not fail?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, char, cout

The source code is as the following.

```
cout << '\\' << endl;  //OK, output is \  
cout << '\\\\' << endl;  //OK, output is an integer 23644, but why?
```

The statement `cout << '\\\\' << endl;` invokes the following function of class `ostream`.

```
_Myt& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL operator<<(int _Val)
```

I know it is strange to write the expression `'\\\\'`, But I don’t understand why it doesn’t fail. How to explain the result?

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Do you think it should fail to compile? If so, with what error? It's not clear why you find this behavior unexpected.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3960954/2491746 for more discussion.

Comment: I like asking this question on the interviews.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. @Simple.

Answer (score 15):

This is a multicharacter literal and has type `int`.

[[lex.ccon]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#2):

> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the execution character
>   set, is conditionally-supported, has type int, and has an implementation-defined value.

You should use `"\\\\"`, which is `char const[3]`: two \ and a NUL byte at the end.