# Why is 2 characters in char allowed in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, char, cout

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and I accidentally wrote two characters in a char, and, for some reason, the code compiled and I got an output on the screen (not even a warning).

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << 'a ';
    std::string temp;
    std::getline(std::cin, temp);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is consistently:

```
24864
```

What's the logic behind the output?

Comment: That's because VC++ tries to implement the C++ Standard, and the C++ Standard describes what character literals are (which include the construction in your code).

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal) contains the answer.

Comment: Aha. The vaunted 'implementation defined.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because those are so-called 'multi char' literals. On most current implementations, they can have up to 4 individual characters in them.