# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] error in Arduino c serial communication

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm coding my BB-8 project and I'm using bluetooth with my Arduino so I'm using:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    state = Serial.read();
```

Most people send numbers through like this which works:

```
if (state == '1') {
```

But I would like to send a string through instead, of a number to make it easier like this:

```
if (state == 'stop') {    // or go etc.
```

But this doesn't seem like it would work so I tried using a string:

```
if (state == "stop") {
```

But I get this error

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Which one would work and if neither what should I do instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that is link to C?

Comment: @Stargateur I considered removing the tag, but this question in particular can be easily answered by both C and C++ programmers.

Answer (score 0):

First off, apostrophes are for **char literals not strings**, that is `'x'` is of type `char` whereas `"x"` is of type `char*`. It is not clearly defined what `'xyz'` means, as discussed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3961219/607407

The value `Serial.read` returns is of type `int`. So in this case:

```
if (state == "stop")
```

You are comparing `int` with `const char*`. Instead, you probably want to read a string and compare that. Here is an example of reading string on arduino from serial:

```
const int max_len = 20;
char input_string[max_len+1]; // Allocate some space for the string
size_t index = 0;

while(Serial.available() > 0) // Don't read unless
{
    if(max_len < 19) // One less than the size of the array
    {
        int input_num = Serial.read(); // Read a character
        input_string[index] = (char)input_num; // Store it
        index++; // Increment where to write next
        input_string[index] = '\0'; // Null terminate the string
    }
    else {
        // all data read, time to data processing
        break;
    }
}
// Don't forget that you have to compare
// strings using strcmp
if(strcmp(inData, "stop") == 0) {
    // do something
}
// reset the buffer so that
// you can read another string
index = 0;
```

Comment: Char literals can be composed of multiple characters.

Comment: Interesting to know. But apparently there is no standard definition on what do they do or mean.

Comment: @KerrekSB but I believe that usage is non-portable, you need to see how your compiler handles it. And you certainly wouldn't want to compare it to the result of a single `read`.

Comment: @TomášZato: Well, the Standard defines their meaning to be implementation-defined...

Comment: @KerrekSB And what is the practical difference between "implementation defined" and "not defined"? Implementation defines all aspects that are not defined.

Comment: @TomášZato: The difference is that if something is implementation-defined, the implementation is required to document it.