# Print multiple characters, formatted as an integer

Tags: c, gcc

Whenever I run this program, It gives output **12592**.
I couldn't find the logic behind it. It it in C Programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("%d",'10');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: '1' is 0x31 and '0' is 0x30. As a multibyte-character, this makes 0x3130, which is decimal 12592

Comment: Thank you so much.. @Ctx

Comment: @Jǝssǝ No, a character literal is of type "int", so the format specifier and the argument are consistent.

Comment: @Ctx but why the compiler is converting it into hexadecimal??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ multicharacter literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal)

Comment: @Stan: No, don't link duplicates to C++, there are differences in this area, e.g. in C++ `'1'` is a `char` type.

Comment: @Bathsheba although that question was asking "C++", the OP quoted the C99 standard, which stated the multi-character literal was ***implementation-defined*** (ISO/IEC 9899 6.4.4.4 Character constants P10).

Answer (score 6):

`'10'` is actually a *multi-character* constant.

It has a type `int`, just like say `'1'`, but its actual value is *implementation defined*.

Quite feasibly its value is `'1' * 256 + '0'` which is 12592 on your platform which is, from what I can tell, using ASCII *encoding*.

Comment: why does it behave that way? why take hexadecimal representation and not simply ascii?

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri it's actually the decimal representation, not hexa. And it does not output as ASCII because you gave the flag `%d` in your format string

Comment: so if you are giving `%d`, then why specifically convert it to hexa? I am not getting that part

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else has said, you are using a *multi-character constant*, and their explanations tell you WHY you get the result you get, as asked.

If you *intended* to print out the *integer literal* value 10 (so far not commented about directly), use

```
printf("%d",10);
```

Note there are no single quotes on the second parameter.

For that matter,

```
printf("10");
```

OR

```
printf("%s","10");
```

(print the *string literal*) would do just as well.

Answer (score 1):

In C (and C++), the apostrophe character `'` is used to form a *character constant*.  Normally, what goes between the apostrophes is *one single character* like `'A'`, or an escape sequence representing one single character, like `'\n'` or `'\001'` or `'\x01'`.

For historical reasons, it's permissible to put multiple actual characters between the apostrophes, as in `'AB'`, or the case you asked about, `'10'`.  These are called *multi-character character constants*.

This is a questionable thing to do.  The result is *implementation defined*, meaning it may do different things under different compilers (although the documentation should tell you what it does).  It may also be quite different between C and C++.

Since it's not well-defined what it does, and since there are few good uses for it even if it were well-defined, the usual advice is to just not use multi-character character constants.  (And if you don't use them, you don't even have to know what they do.)

Under most C compilers, what you get when you do this is the result of "appending" the two characters in memory -- that is, creating a 16-bit number by putting two 8-bit numbers next to each other. (For now I'm assuming just two characters in the multi-character character constant, although actually there might be even more).  It may be easiest to explain this with an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d (%02x) %d (%02x) -> %d (%02x)\n", 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'AB', 'AB');
    printf("%d (%02x) %d (%02x) -> %d (%02x)\n", '1', '1', '0', '0', '10', '10');
}
```

On my machine this prints

```
65 (41) 66 (42) -> 16706 (4142)
49 (31) 48 (30) -> 12592 (3130)
```

(But, side note, on my machine my compiler gives me the message "warning: multi-character character constant", reinforcing the notion that multi-character character constants are usually a bad idea.)

Looking at the second example as bytes in memory; '1' looks like

`+------+`            `+----------+`
`| 0x31 |`     or    `| 00110001 |`
`+------+`            `+----------+`

And '10' looks like

`+------+------+`            `+----------+----------+`
`| 0x31 | 0x30 |`     or    `| 00110001 | 00110000 |`
`+------+------+`            `+----------+----------+`

Where does that number 12592 come from?  It's the decimal representation of the hexadecimal number 0x3130.  Or, stated another way, it's 256 × 49 + 48.