# How to recognize space after first word in string?

Tags: c

I have created a very simple program that is supposed to match a string where the first word ("abc") ends with a white space. If I write, for example, "abc defg" I should receive a match because of "abc" and the white space. If I write "abcdefg" I should not because there are no white space.

I guess my first solution didn't really work out because a white space simply isn't a character (?). I therefore created the second solution below with a second condition in the IF-statement, however, it didn't work out neither...

Any ideas how a space in the end of a string can be recognized ?

```
int main(void) 
{
    while(1)
    {
        char str[30];

        scanf("%s", str);

        char *word = "abc ";      <------------ QUESTION HERE

        // If two first three letters are "abc" + white space
        if(strncmp(str, word, 4) == 0) {

            printf("Match\n");

        } else {

            printf("No match\n");

        }
    }

}
```

Second code:

```
int main(void) 
{
    while(1)
    {
        char str[30];

        scanf("%s", str);

        char *word = "abc";

        // If two first three letters are "abc" + white space
        if(strncmp(str, word, 3) && (isspace(str[3])) == 0) {

            printf("Match\n");

        } else {

            printf("No match\n");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try this `printf("str = \"%s\"\n", str);`

Comment: What's `abc[3]` in the second solution, shouldn't it be `isspace(str[3])`?

Comment: BTW: `scanf("%s"...` will not read in a white space but will stop reading in right before

Comment: Stephan: Yes, I changed it. Tormund: Will try and return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess my first solution didn't really work out because a white space simply isn't a character (?)

Of course whitespace is a character - in fact, a group of characters are considered whitespace. However, whitespace characters play special role when it comes to `scanf`: it serves to separate inputs parsed with the format string, except a few special cases.

That is why you are not going to get `"abc "` from `scanf` with `%s`: the trailing whitespace would always be ignored, so neither of your two approaches would work.

This would work:

```
char buf[100], ch;
scanf("%99s%c", buf, &ch);
if (strcmp(buf, "abc") == 0 && ch == ' ') {
    printf("Yes!\n");
}
```

The idea is to read the character immediately after `%s`'s capture into a variable, and compare that variable to space character `' '`.

Note the use of `%99s` to limit the size of the input to the allocated length of the buffer (plus an additional character for the null terminator).

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/QXoM4m)

**Important:** It goes without saying that you need to check the return value of `scanf` to see that there was some input for all format specifiers. In the case above you need to check that `scanf`'s return value was `2`.

Comment: You should check the return code from scanf; if there is no whitespace in the input, you will be comparing an uninitialised value (or two, if input is at EOF).

Comment: Thank you a lot! :) I actually managed to isolate the problem even more and it kind of work when I replaced doubble quotes with single quotes ('abc') but in the end I didn't manage to transfer the solution into this specific function. I guess that was luck though because I had no idea about what I was doing...

Comment: @rici Right, I added a note at the bottom to mention this. Thank you!

Comment: @Lavonen Using single quotes around multiple characters, as in `'abc'` [creates a multicharacter literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3960954/335858), which is something you seldom want.