# C++ and the Integer Value of Characters

Tags: c++

I was in lab recently when my professor noticed another student using a switch statement with characters. He noticed that it allowed "case '==':" and from there we went down a rabbit hole of what number does this equate to and how did it come to that.

I could find anything via google, so when I got home I did some maths and came up with the formula in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int a = 'b';

    int b = 'bb';

    std::cout << a << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << (a * 256) + a << std::endl << std::endl;

    int c = 'bbb';

    std::cout << c << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << (a * 256 + a) * 256 + a << std::endl << std::endl;

    int d = 'abcd';
    std::cout << d << std::endl << std::endl;

    int e = ((97 * 256 + 98) * 256 + 99) * 256 + 100;
    std::cout << e << std::endl << std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

This provides the following output:

```
98

25186

25186

6447714

6447714

1633837924

1633837924
```

So, I figured out the math behind it, I was just wondering if anyone knew the why they chose to resolve it like this or could provide a real world example where this might be useful? It seems pretty math heavy for multi character switch statements.

Comment: This is not standard C++, basically implementation defined behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal