# C++ Displaying a vector

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, stream

I'm learning C++ so my question might seem a bit stupid. I wanted to build a function that print every element in a vector. I come up with that but it seems to display the address of every element. I google it and find a nice solution but i wanted to do it this way so if anyone can explain me where i'm doing something wrong. 
My code :

```
void display_vector(std::vector<int>& to_display);


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector_to_sort = { 2,6,7,2,1,80,2,59,8,9 };


    display_vector(vector_to_sort);
}

void display_vector(std::vector<int> &to_display)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < to_display.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << to_display[i] << ', ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The solution i found on internet :

```
#include <iterator>

void display_vector(const vector<int> &v)
{
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Output of my code :

21129661129671129621129611129680112962112965911296811296911296

Comment: Why did you decide that " it seems to display the address of every element"?  Show the output.

Comment: Your bug is here: ', ' You used the wrong quotation mark. " is for a string literal ' is for a single character

Comment: @drescherjm I should write ", " ?

Comment: Yes, use ", " instead of ', '

Comment: @drescherjm Thank I will google what's the difference now

Comment: By using the wrong quotation mark you ended up creating a multi-character literal: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c)

Comment: @Kiyosuke [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use ", " instead of ', '.

You can use any of the following print mechanism in the `display()` function:

```
void display_vector(std::vector<int> &to_display)
{
    //by using Normal for loop
    for (auto i = to_display.begin(); i != to_display.end(); ++i) {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    //by using Range based for loop
    for (int & i : to_display) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
std::cout << to_display[i] << ', ';
                              ^^^^^^
```

you are using a multybyte character literal that has an implementation defined value.

Substitute it for string literal `", "`.

As for the function then for starters if the vector is not being changed in the function then the parameter should be a constant reference.

You can use the range-based for loop to outfput elements of the vector like for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream & display_vector( const std::vector<int> &to_display, std::ostream &os = std::cout );

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector_to_sort = { 2,6,7,2,1,80,2,59,8,9 };

    display_vector(vector_to_sort) << '\n';
}

std::ostream & display_vector( const std::vector<int> &to_display, std::ostream &os )
{
    for ( const auto &item : to_display )
    {
        os << item << ", ";
    }

    return os;
}
```

Using such a function you can for example output the vector in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace below line

```
std::cout << to_display[i] << ', ';
```

with

```
std::cout << to_display[i] << ", ";
```

Also note that if you just want to display vector in function then declare parameter as **const reference** as shown below

```
void display_vector(const std::vector<int> &to_display);
```

Answer (score 0):

The debuggers make it easy to examine vectors but I include a simple template to print out vectors of standard types and often use it when debugging data that I wish to look at with other tools.

```
template<class T>
void print(const std::vector<T>& v){
for (auto x: v)
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```