# When is a multi-character constant useful?

Tags: c++

In Microsoft Detours Library, they do: `const ULONG DETOUR_REGION_SIGNATURE = 'Rrtd';`

I'm trying to figure out exactly WHY they do this. When I print it on my system it prints: `1383232612`

which is the same as:
`(0x52 << 24) | (0x72 << 16) | (0x74 << 8) | 0x64` 
or 
`('R' << 24) + ('r' << 16) + ('t' << 8) + 'd'`

Why do they do this? I read it's not portable and depends entirely on the endianness of the system and it gives warnings when compiling with GCC and Clang..

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c)

Comment: It's probably just a unique number, being a number it is easier to compare than a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When is a multi-character constant useful?

When you want some arbitrary constant integer value that **looks** like text when interpreted as a sequence of characters. This apparent "textuality" is occasionally useful for the programmer to quickly recognise the constant from binary soup.

For example, let's consider a binary protocol or file format that contains a message. Let's say there are N possible messages including "configure", "push" and "plop". We can encode the message as an integer. `enum` is useful here:

```
enum message {
    CONFIGURE,
    PUSH,
    PLOP,
    ...
};
```

Now, when the programmer observes such file in a hex editor, it will show all of those messages as `....` in text because those bytes do not represent a printable character, or possibly `02 00` in hex. Why does `02 00` mean "plop"? There is no connection.

Instead, we could give those four bytes values that do have meaningful representation as text:

```
enum message {
    CONFIGURE = 'CONF',
    PUSH      = 'PUSH',
    PLOP      = 'PLOP',
    ...
};
```

Now, that same message looks like `PLOP` in textual representation. It is immediately obvious what the message means.

But the integer value that has such textual representation is system specific, which brings us to what you mentioned:

> I read it's not portable

And this is when multi-chraracter constant is not useful: When writing portable programs. Microsoft Detours Library that you used as the example presumably does not care about portability.

Comment: It is, or can be made, portable, so long as you know what endian the source/destination file is relative to the native endian of the code consuming/producing it.