# What is the most efficient way to replace \\n with \n

Tags: c++, sfml

I ask this because I am using SFML strings. sf::String does not insert a new line in the presence of a \n.

I can't seem to figure out a way without using 3/4 STL algorithms.

`std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](const char&c](return c == '\\n'), '\n'`});
does not work. The string remains the same.

I have also tried replacing the `\\` occurrence with a temporary, say `~`. This works, but when I go to replace the `~` with `\`, then it adds a `\\` instead of a `\`

I have produced a solution by manually replacing and deleting duplicates after `\n` insertion :

```
for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it == '\\') {
        if (it + 1 != str.end()) {
            if (*(it + 1) != 'n') continue;
            *it = '\n';
            str.erase(it + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `std::replace`?

Comment: I have tried, but it does not work.

Comment: Then at least add the code that you tried, and describe how it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you considered just looping over the string manually? `for (auto& c : str) { ... }`

Comment: `'\\n'` [isn't what you would like it to be](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal#Notes).

Comment: @Tas I have. It just reverts to its original.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful, because it sounds like you have multiple bugs.

Comment: '\\n' is a multi-character literal you certainly don't want that.  ) Also I am not sure you want to do what you think you need to do.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Always enable all warnings. You'll definitely get one for `'\\n'`

Answer (score 3):

You might do:

```
str = std::regex_replace(str, std::regex(R"(\\n)"), "\n")
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/330e7e0b6ff0fa07)

Comment: My compiler does not let me do this. I get an error for some reason?

Comment: All of this back-and-forth could be reduced immensely by asking the right question: include a [mcve] in your question (it should be like 5 lines long!), mention what compiler you're using and IDE. There's no set rule on what version of C++ people who answer questions use, though it's typically _at least_ C++11 (which is 10 years old). If you only have support for an older version like C++03 you should specify

Comment: Added demo link and a "typo".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `'\\n'` is not a single character but two characters. So it needs to be stored in a string `"\\n"`. But now `std::replace_if` doesn't work because it operates on elements and the elements of a `std::string` are single characters.

You can write a new function to replace sub-strings within a string and call that instead. For example:

```
std::string& replace_all(std::string& s, std::string const& from, std::string const& to)
{
    if(!from.empty())
        for(std::string::size_type pos = 0; (pos = s.find(from, pos) + 1); pos += to.size())
            s.replace(--pos, from.size(), to);
    return s;
}

// ...

std::string s = "a\\nb\\nc";

std::cout << s << '\n';

replace_all(s, "\\n", "\n");

std::cout << s << '\n';
```

Comment: It might be two characters `{'\\', 'n'}`... it might be three characters `{'\\', '\\', 'n'}` ... hard to say for sure.