# Conditions that won't accept letters from the alphabet

Tags: c++

> How do make a condition in c++ that says you can't put letters from
> the alphabet? Well, I know how to do it manually but is there any way
> that you can't do it manually? I tried using the java code method but
> it didn't work(well it won't work really because it's from java not
> CPP)

```
if(choice == 'A-Za-z')
{
cout<<"No alphabet please"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: 'A-Za-z' is a mulitcharacter literal. It won't do what you want at  all. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c)

Comment: You need to use regex or if you're looking at a single character, you can look at the ascii value of the character by using `int(char)` and see if it's within 65-90 or 97-122

Comment: How to not manually put letters a to z but get the same result?

Comment: Hint: Start with [`isalpha()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha).

Comment: @RussellIslam It's better to use constants like `'a'` and `'z'` than hard-coded raw ASCII numbers. These are much harder to get wrong.

Comment: Is choice a `char` in this code?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `isalpha()` in C++.

```cpp
if(isalpha(choice)){
 cout<<"No alphabet please"<<endl;
}
```

Refer `isalpha()` in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha/) or [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) for more info.

Comment: It's not `c.isalpha()`, it's `isalpha(c)`.

Comment: My bad. Changed it.

Comment: It's worth noting that [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) is usually a better resource than cplusplus.com is.

Comment: How about if its a number?

Comment: @LickMe Refer `isdigit()` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex: **/^[A-Za-z]+$/**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main () {
    if (std::regex_match ("You Input", std::regex("^[A-Za-z]+$") ))
        std::cout << "string literal matched\n";
}
```

[reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/cpp_regex_match.htm)

Answer (score 0):

im only using .c file . sorry for the late answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

void main() {
char a;

do {
    rewind(stdin);
    printf("enter a value>");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    
} while (isalpha(a) == 0);
printf("invalid input");
}
```

so when the user inputs a character the loop will come to an end.