# Can anyone help me to find an error in this code?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
    
int gvalue=10;


void extra(){
cout<< gvalue<<'  ';
}


int main()
{
    extra();
    {
        int gvalue=20;
        cout<<gvalue<<' ';
        cout<<gvalue<<' ';
    }
}
```

The output which I got was:  10822420 20

I cannot get what is the error?
&
what does the below section of code mean & work?

```
extra();
{
    int gvalue=20;
    cout<<gvalue<<' ';
    cout<<gvalue<<' ';
}
```

Thanks in advance..!!
Ignore the bad English.

Comment: Is `'  '` a typo? Did you mean to use a multi character constant?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Change `cout<< gvalue<<'  ';` to `cout<< gvalue<<' ';` or `cout<< gvalue<<"  ";` for the value that you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

`'  '` (note that there are two spaces between apostrophes) is a multi-character literal. Its value is implementation-defined; apparently on your implementation it's `8224` (which happens to be `32 * 256 + 32`, in case you are wondering where this number came from; 32 is the ASCII code of the space `' '`).

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: One more thing I want to ask?
What does it mean to have parenthesis after I called the function?
Like how does it differ if I just paste the code without parenthesis

Comment: Can you explain what line of code you are talking about. You can't remove the parenthesis here: `extra();` that would totally change the meaning and make the code do nothing.

Comment: The braces are unrelated to the function call. It's just a block aka a [compound statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Compound_statements). It's redundant here - braces can be removed without changing the meaning of the program.