# How to print array with looping with C

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

I want to make programs that request integer input from the user. if the user enters 0, it will display "Sunday", if the user enters 1, the program will display "Monday" and so on until "Saturday". If the user enters a value outside the range 0 to 6, the program writes "Invalid Days". but when I input a integer the array of days didnt show up. What should I do ?

This is "code.cpp"

```
main(){
    char days[7] = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesdat","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
    
    int i;
    
    printf("Input Integer:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    
    if(i < 0 || i >= 7) {
      printf("invalid days\n");
      return;
    }    

    for (i ; i < 7;i++)
    {
        printf("Days: %d\n", days[i]);
    }
}
```

When i run it at dev C++ it show error,

> 4 91  F:\IPB\PENUGASAN\MATKUL\MATERI - Copy\APLIKOM\C++\UAS\UAS 2.cpp [Error] too many initializers for 'char [7]'
>
> 13    7   F:\IPB\PENUGASAN\MATKUL\MATERI - Copy\APLIKOM\C++\UAS\UAS 2.cpp [Error] return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Why have you named a file with a C program with `.cpp`? Are you compiling this with a C++ compiler?

Comment: `%d` for zero terminated character array literals? Sure??

Comment: don't use `i <= 7` but instead use `i < 7` as you only have 6 (counting from 0 days).

Comment: `'Sunday'` [is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c) what you think it is.

Comment: There are a lot of errors, you can start where the compiler suggested "too many initializers for 'char [7]'", you allocated 7 characters and is initializing with 7 strings

Answer (score -5):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char* days[7] = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesdat","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
    
    int i;
    
    printf("Input Integer:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    
    if(i < 0 || i >= 7) {
      printf("invalid days\n");
      return 0;
    }    

    for (i ; i < 7;i++)
    {
        printf("Days: %s\n", days[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually run this? What did it print?

Comment: Didn't run it but the code looks good it's a simple question.

Comment: Well, run it, see what it does print.

Comment: Don't have a compiler can't run it, tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: `'Sunday'` [is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/multicharacter-literal-in-c-and-c) what you think it is.

Comment: ahh Multi-quotes not there eh?, finished should be good now

Comment: Please test the code you use in an answer, or at least mention that you have not tested the code in the answer itself. Also, in any case, you need to explain why and how the shown code solves the OP's problem.

Comment: char days[7]? that's just a string, not an array of strings

Comment: 13 7 F:\IPB\UAS  2.cpp [Error] return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]

Comment: 4 91 F:\IPB\UAS 2.cpp [Error] too many initializers for 'char [7]'

Comment: Error Log looks like that guys

Comment: fixed try again.