# Can I replace a single character in a string with 2 characters?

Tags: c++, string, replace

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

void foo(std::string &s) {
    replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'S', 'TH');
}
```

I want `foo(s)` to replace each `S` in `s` with the two characters `TH`. For example

```
std::string s = "SAT";
foo(s);
std::cout << s << "\n" // THAT
```

However, the definition of `foo` gives me an error.

> Error (active) E0304   no instance of function template "std::replace" matches the argument list

Why does this not work?

Comment: Have you used std namespace? Try std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'S', 'TH)

Comment: 'TH' is not valid syntax >for character literals<. Only single characters are enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @gerum it is valid, mutlicharacter literals are conditionally supported, they are of type `int`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571914/4117728

Comment: You are right I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::replace` cannot do it, but you can use `std::regex_replace` instead.

```
#include <regex>

std::string s = "SAT";
s = regex_replace(s, std::regex("S"), "TH");
std::cout << s << "\n"; // output: THAT
```

Comment: you don't need a regex, `std::string::replace` can do it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, tbh, I tried to find a solution with string::replace, but didn't manage. It's never late to post your answer in a comment, I am learning from mistakes too!

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/1434nfTT5, though return value of `find` should be checked. I find strings memebr functions confusing too, because they have similar names as algorithms but work with indices rather than iterators, can be rather confusing