# assiging 31 to char and printing it again as int

Tags: c

I have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
        char c='31';
        printf("%d\n",c);

}
```

The above one prints wrong 49. It should have printed 31. Can this be done in C. I believe `31` is not number 31 that means '31' is not represented as binary `00011111`=31 so is this true so it can't be done or make sense doing it in C

Comment: `'31'` is not a char and obviously can't be stored in a single char. Enable all warnings and read it, you'll see what's wrong with your problem. For the numeric value use `char c = 31`. See [Multicharacter literal in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3960954/995714)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Is `char c=31;` what you actually want?

Comment: @kaylum I like to know are '31' and 31 same or different

Comment: Note that `'3'` also is not a `char` in C, but an `int`.  The unexpected result is not so much one of type, but of value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code did not assign 31**

To assign 31, use:

```
    //char c='31';
    char c = 31;  // drop the ''
```

**Multi-byte character constant**

`'31'` is a *multi-byte character constant* with an implementation specific value.  In OP's case, it is an `int` with likely the ASCII values 51 for `'3'` and 49 for `'1'`  joined together in big-endian fashion as a base-256 number or `51*256 + 49`.

Since this value is outside the `char` range, it is converted as part of the assignment - likely by only retaining the least significant 8-bits - to 49.  This is what OP saw.

**Save time**

Enable all compiler warnings.  Most of the time, coding a multi-byte character constant is a coding error.  Multi-byte character constants are rarely used and often discouraged by various style standards.
There are an old feature of C not often used today due to the implementations details of `int` size, endian and character encoding make for difficulties in portable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign 31 to char, just assign it as follows

```c
char c = 31;
```

31 means int which will easily fit into 8bits .

Answer (score 0):

Char type will only take **one** letter, number, or symbol. The char c will equal '3', then '1' will override it. The int value of of '1' is 49.

int -- %d
char -- %c
string -- %s

try

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c[3] = {'3','1','\0'};
    printf("%s\n",c);
}
```

Comment: `The char c will equal '3', then '1' will override it` this is completely wrong. The value is implementation defined