# What is the different between IF ELSE and SWITCH CASE in C++ programming?

Tags: c++, codelite

i am in the beginning of learing C++ and having difficult on using SWITCH case since its case can only be apply to integer or character but some people on this web show that they can be apply to string like the code below:

```
switch(a) {
  case 'hello': // a == 'hello'
    print('right!')
    break // You should add this
  case 'hi': // a == 'hi'
    print('left!')
    break
  default: // this executes if no equality was met in the values above.
    print('wrong!')
}
```

but i try to redo it in my codelite and VScode but it doesn't work so can anyone point out the mistake or give me the better example ? That will be truly amazing.
[i was try this but it aint work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENOyv.png)

Comment: [Why do multicharacter literals exist in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/why-do-multicharacter-literals-exist-in-c-and-c) is worth a read.

Comment: First please note the difference between a double-quoted string like `"string"`, and a single-quoted character like `'c'`.

Comment: the code i show was from a comment of another post, so i only copy it since he said that it is the right thing todo.

Comment: "*the code i show was from a comment of another post*" That text is almost certainly too big to be from a comment on Stack Overflow. Also, it's not surprising to find people who have written non-functional code online. Lastly, don't post screenshots of text; copy the text into the question itself.

Comment: @Hiếu Nguyễn Chính How is the variable a declared?

Comment: Don't believe everything you read "on the web", especially about C++.

Comment: @NicolBolas tks for the advice, and as i said i am new to this so be gentle with me.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i only written " int a;" , as which i am learning from it only do the case with arithmetic operator. And i want to do something different with string or like the first comment " multicharacter ". It is easier to do this one with if else but i want to master each case first.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik people do tell me to try swift for developing IOS app, but i want to do more thing than just making money right here so i find that C++ is the most suitable one.

Comment: It's not C++, its missing terminating ';' characters. It could be golang, the ';' are optional and it supports strings in `switch()` (C++ does not) while having a similar syntax (`break` is not needed, but I think it's harmless).

Comment: If you're truly serious about learning C++, you need to invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). While it's possible to find good online tutorials and videos, about 99% of everything online (that isn't paid) is crap.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Do not forget public libraries. Some of the good books are still good a few years after their publishing. Reading the homework-related questions here, it seems very possible to find some which are more up to date than what some professors teach. ;-)

Comment: Sturgeon's revelation is in full force in C++.

Comment: Reminder:  always search the internet (and StackOverflow) before posting to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement requires "integral" (or enum) cases. This means you cannot add a string as a case unless you get a "compile time integer" out of it.

There is a way of doing so, which can come in handy when converting back and forth from enum values and their string representations or when you want to generate jump tables from string cases:

```cpp
constexpr unsigned long hash(char const *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c = 0;

    while ((c = *str++))
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}

constexpr unsigned long operator ""_sh(char const *str, size_t) {
    return hash(str);
}

int main ()
{
    const char *a = "hello";
    
    switch(hash(a)) {
    case "hello"_sh:
        printf("right!");
        break;
    case "hi"_sh:
        printf("left!");
        break;
    default: 
        printf("wrong!");
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/159553db9b1c97c3)

In the code above, your strings are hashed at compile time. This means that if you had a hash collision the code would not compile (so you can change your hashing algorithm - I used one from [here](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Eoz/hash.html)). When all is good your strings will map to numbers and you can emulate `switch` statement with string cases.

### EDIT:

As with any method that hashes strings for indexing, **when the input string (`a` above) does not come from a fixed set** there can be a "false positive" i.e. an `a` that hashes to one of the existing cases but does not equal the case label. To guard against this case, one can check inside the switch case and jump to the default case in case of a false positive e.g.

```cpp
#define NO_FALSE_POSITIVE(a, b) \
    if (strcmp((a), (b))) goto FALSE_POSITIVE

switch(hash(a)) {
    case "hello"_sh:
        NO_FALSE_POSITIVE("hello", a);
        printf("right!");
        break;
    case "hi"_sh:
        NO_FALSE_POSITIVE("hi", a);
        printf("left!");
        break;
    default:
    FALSE_POSITIVE: 
        printf("wrong!");
}
```

This implies a constant +1 check only for the chosen case, instead of cascading if-else blocks which can result to N comparisons, so the optimization continues to worth the effort. It's easy to imagine further macro wrapping (I've seen `CASE` labels in production code) to remove the verbosity in this, but I wouldn't recommend it; if your use-case needs complicated validation maybe you're better off using if-else or unordered map with the case strings as keys.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a problem with your code is that it doesn't account for collisions on the input-string. It could result in accidentially switching to "case hello" for a="abcdefg" (ficticious example), if that string produces the same hash.

Comment: I am using string hash inside `switch` in our code base as well, I think this is a good idea, although there is a risk of collision. In typical case, this should not be a problem with `enum`  like strings: collisions would be detected at compile time (duplicate `case`). But the quality of this hashing is low I think, it could be improved and having a 64-bit integer greatly reduces the risk of collision. For reference, Lua hashes like this: `h = h ^ ((h<<5)+(h>>2)+(uint8_t)*str);`

Comment: @Juliean added an edit to discuss how I've seen this case handled.

Comment: @prapin Somehow Lua always pops up when discussing hashing. I'm using the `djb2` which is supposedly a very good non-cryptographic choice, but maybe I should benchmark (collision probability / performance) how it compares to the Lua one. That's a good idea thanks

Comment: I don't like this. What happens if two of your case strings hash to the same value? Yes, it will be caught at compile time, but it's still a dreadful kludge.

Comment: @TonyK first time I used it, I had the literals `_sh1`, `_sh2`, `_sh3` which would use different hashing algorithms, just to handle this case. The probability of a set of strings hashing the same in all three of them was 1 in billions. After years of using it I've never come across that case  (and I've had switch statements with hundreds of cases) and the `_sh2,_sh3` serve only as conversation starter