# What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?

Tags: c++, quotes

I'm curious about this code:

```
cout << 'test'; // Note the single quotes.
```

gives me an output of `1952805748`.

My question: Is the output an address in memory or something?

Comment: Pay attention that the actual value is implementation defined http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal

Answer (score 287):

It's a multi-character literal. `1952805748` is `0x74657374`, which decomposes as

```
0x74 -> 't'
0x65 -> 'e'
0x73 -> 's'
0x74 -> 't'
```

**Edit:**

> ***C++ standard, §2.14.3/1 - Character literals***
>
> (...) An ordinary character literal that contains more than
> one c-char is a multicharacter literal . A multicharacter literal has type int and implementation-deﬁned
> value.

Comment: I suppose the funnest thing about that definition is that `sizeof(int)` is implementation defined as well. So not only is storage order implementation defined, but the maximum length of these is as well.

Answer (score 78):

No, it's not an address. It's the so-called multibyte character.

Typically, it's the ASCII values of the four characters combined.

```
't' == 0x74; 'e' == 0x65; 's' == 0x73; 't' == 0x74;
```

So 0x74657374 is 1952805748.

But it can also be 0x74736574 on some other compiler. The C and C++ standards both say the value of multibyte characters is *implementation defined*. So generally its use is *strongly* discouraged.

Comment: Is the length of such a multi-byte character constrained to 4 bytes? I.e. does it represent an int written out as characters?

Comment: @Giorgio: The standard only says it's implementation defined, with no more details. In practice, since `int` is 4 bytes on most machines, I don't think it makes sense to use more than 4 bytes. Yes, it was intended to be a convenient way to write some constants, but unfortunately different compilers have been interpreting it differently, so nowadays most coding styles discourage its use.

Comment: @chys: And the fact that it's implementation-defined means it's not even required to be consistent.  A conforming compiler could give all multicharacter literals the value 0, for example (though that would be unfriendly).

Comment: One has to ask why this loony feature exists in the standard. It seems like such a rare use case, is implementation defined anyway, and can be done quite clearly with ordinary bit shifting and or'ing if needed.

Comment: @Boann _Yes_, my sentiments exactly.  But you can safely use it in switches and whatnot, as direct comparison for `==` should check out

Answer (score 18):

> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal has type int and implementation-deﬁned value.

Implementation defined behavior is required to be documented by
the implementation. for example in gcc you can find it [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Characters-implementation.html)

The compiler values a multi-character character constant
a character at a time, shifting the previous value left
by the number of bits per target character, and then
or-ing in the bit-pattern of the new character truncated
to the width of a target character. The final
bit-pattern is given type int, and is therefore signed,
regardless of whether single characters are signed or
not.

Check the explanation in [this page](http://books.google.fr/books?id=3Qiwp2kD4QYC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=C%2b%2b%20multi%20character%20in%20single%20quote&source=bl&ots=iQA74CjfW9&sig=aZcKEZvmHebVrwbsqPgiTY1KSqw&hl=fr&ei=3w13Ts-WHsPB0QXVxJycCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q&f=false) for more details

Answer (score 10):

They're really just `int`s.  They're used extensively in the Core Audio API enum's for example, in the `CoreAudioTypes.h` header file,

```
enum
{
    kAudioFormatLinearPCM               = 'lpcm',
    kAudioFormatAC3                     = 'ac-3',
    kAudioFormat60958AC3                = 'cac3',
    kAudioFormatAppleIMA4               = 'ima4',
    kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC                = 'aac ',
    kAudioFormatMPEG4CELP               = 'celp',
} ;
```

There's a lot of chatter about this not being "platform independent", but when you're using an api that's *made for* a specific platform, who cares about portability.  Checking for equality on the same platform will never fail.  These `enum`'d values are easier to read and they actually contain *their identity in their value*, which is pretty nice.

What I've tried to do below is wrap a multibyte character literal up so it can be printed (on Mac this works).  The strange thing is, if you don't use up all 4 characters, the result becomes wrong below..

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MASK(x,BYTEX) ((x&(0xff<<8*BYTEX))>>(8*BYTEX))

struct Multibyte
{
  union{
    int val ;
    char vals[4];
  };

  Multibyte() : val(0) { }
  Multibyte( int in )
  {
    vals[0] = MASK(in,3);
    vals[1] = MASK(in,2);
    vals[2] = MASK(in,1);
    vals[3] = MASK(in,0);
  }
  char operator[]( int i ) {
    return val >> (3-i)*8 ; // works on mac
    //return val>>i*8 ; // might work on other systems
  }

  void println()
  {
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
      putc( vals[i], stdout ) ;
    puts( "" ) ;
  }
} ;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  Multibyte( 'abcd' ).println() ;  
  Multibyte( 'x097' ).println() ;
  Multibyte( '\"\\\'\'' ).println() ;
  Multibyte( '/*|' ).println() ;
  Multibyte( 'd' ).println() ;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Checking for equality on the same platform will never fail."_ It might. Upgrade to Visual Studio _xyz_ and bite your tongue. This library has made a _terrible_ decision.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  *"Upgrade to Visual Studio xyz and bite your tongue."*    Core Audio API is OS X's system audio API so this is not relevant.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier: Fine; upgrade your OSX Clang version and bite your tongue...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Or just use a different compiler altogether. The behavior is *compiler-dependent*, not *platform-dependent*. A platform dependency would be assuming that in the default environment, `$HOME` always stores a value that begins with `/Users/`. If the library is always compiled at the same time as its dependencies, it's not a terrible idea (just a bad one), but the binary format persists for someone to take a dependency on, this is a nightmare waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of feature is really good when you are building parsers.
Consider this:

```
byte* buffer = ...;
if(*(int*)buffer == 'GET ')
  invoke_get_method(buffer+4);
```

This code will likely only work on specific endianess and might break across different compilers