# Strings between quotation marks in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)

The following code compiles in C++:

```
unsigned int x;
x = 'abc';
```

What does it mean? Is putting string between quotation marks legal? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not a string, but a multi character literal. See [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters). (Vote to close as duplicated)