# C++ escape code parameter

Tags: c++, c

I am looking at some code from one of our customers and found this function parameter I've never seen before:

```
some_function('ESFc');
```

In the debugger I set the value to

```
char c = 'ESFc';
```

and it equals 99

He also is using 'ESSc', 'ESCm' and 'ESBd' which eval to 99, 109 and 100

What is this? Is it some kind of escape code?

Comment: Note: ASCII codes for c, m and d are 99, 109 and 100 respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a multi-character literal, but its value is not 99. The type of `'ESFc'` is actually an `int`, and when you store it in a `char` it loses precision. See this question:

[What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters/7459943)

Comment: I believe C does not support multi-character literals while C++ does.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I wouldn't know about that, but I'd assume C supports them as well. Yet his question is tagged C++ and even says C++ in the title.

Comment: The tags are both C++ and C, and sometimes StackOverflow decides to add a tag to the title.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: StackOverflow does that? Still C does support multi-literal characters as well.

Comment: @MarkRansom: "sometimes StackOverflow decides to add a tag to the title" is news to me.  Is this discussed somewhere on meta?

Comment: Sorry, it appears I was confused - C and C++ both support multi-character literals. There is a difference between C and C++ with single-character literals, but that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I think my brain is just breaking down this afternoon. I should delete every comment on this thread.