# Multibyte Integers Variables in C

Tags: c, ascii

I'd like to know, how to calculate integer values of strings in single quotes `' '`.

My sample code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = 'aA';
    int d = 'Aa';

    printf( "%d %d" , c, d);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
24897 16737
```

What are those numbers? Is there any formula to calculate them ?

Comment: That is wrong, you have to use double quotes on strings.

Comment: @Nick Oh really? No, not at all.

Comment: @H2CO3 are multibyte integers considered strings?

Comment: @Nick No, they aren't. **But:** what OP has is valid, it just means something different.

Comment: At one time, this was closed as a duplicate of [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)   Given that the alternative is a C++ question and this is C, it is not altogether surprising that someone objected and removed the duplicate information — but the fact that it was marked as a duplicate is still recorded.  Not sure what to do best, but at least you don't have to go hunting through the edit history to find the purported duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are:

1. **not strings!**
2. multibyte integers, of which the value is implementation-defined, but it is usually calculated using this formula:

   `integer value of 1st character multiplied by (2 << CHAR_BITS) + integer value of 2nd character`

So, assuming your C locale uses ASCII and you have 8-bit bytes, `'aA'` becomes

```
97 * 256 + 65
```

which is 24897.

Multicharacter literals are of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

It is the value of  multi-character character stored in your variables

Answer (score 1):

The value of a multi-character constant is implementation-defined.

> **§ 6.4.4.4 Character constants**
>   The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
>   `'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
>   execution character, is implementation-defined.