# multichar set c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)

One of the new students in our University asked me to help hem with some code. 
his code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    cout << ('/0'); //his mistake - the / is upside down
    system("pause");
}
```

(this code was made with VS2008) 
he expected to get a blank char, he got 12080. 
I fond the mistake, but I still don't understand why he got 12080.

can someone explain this? is it different between platforms?

Answer (score 1):

ASCII code

```
/ - 2F
0 - 30

Hex to DEC 
2F30 - 12080
```