# getline using strings in C++ returning error: No instance of overloaded function getline matches the argument list

Tags: c++, getline

I'm trying to parse a document using getline to take an entire line and place it in the string variable named 'line.' The problem is I'm getting an error that says: "No instance of overloaded function getline matches the argument list." Can anyone help me solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "recordsOffice.h"

using namespace std;

RecordsOffice::RecordsOffice()
{

}

void RecordsOffice::parseCommands (string commandsFileName)
{
//String to hold a line from the file
string line;

//Open the file
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open(commandsFileName);

// Check to make sure the file opened properly
if (!myFile.is_open())
{
    cout << "There was an error opening " << commandsFileName << "." << endl;
    return;
}

//Parse the document
while (getline(myFile, line, '/n'))
{
    if (line[0] == 'A')
    {
        addStudent(line);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your escape sequence is backward - try replacing

```
/n
```

With

```
\n
```

Multicharacter character liberals in C++ have type `int`, rather than type `char`, which is causing the arguments to `std::getline` to have the wrong type. (Thanks to @chris for pointing out that the type will be `int` specifically!)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow. I can't believe it's something that small. Thank you very much. That fixed the problem.

Comment: It's a multicharacter literal, which is an `int`.

Comment: @chris- Is that behavior standardized?  Or is that just how some compilers handle this?

Comment: @templatetypedef C++ standard, §2.14.3/1 - Character Literals. [**This answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7459943/759019) has the details.