# Printing out strings from 2D string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, 2d

So, my array looks like this:

```
string links[26][4];
links[0][0] = 'A';
links[0][1] = 'WOL-LA-CHEE';
```

And if I try to print let's say 'WOL-LA-CHEE' like this:

cout << links[0][1]

my output looks like this:

E

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `'WOL-LA-CHEE'` is a multicharacter literal. You want a string literal.

Answer (score 5):

If you put text between single quotes, that denotes a character literal. Since there are copy constructors for `std::string` from `char` and `const char *`, this works for one character, but it doesn't do what you think it does for multiple characters. You most likely want to put the strings between double quotes:

```
 links[0][1] = "WOL-LA-CHEE";
```

[Stuff to read about multicharacter literals.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)

Answer (score 2):

Put the string in double quotes. `"WOL-LA-CHEE"`. Single quotes declare a character constant, whose value is unspecified in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`'WOL-LA-CHEE'` is a multicharacter literal. It has implementation-defined value and is an `int`. It seems that you want a string literal instead:

```
links[0][0] = "A";
links[0][1] = "WOL-LA-CHEE";
```

Assigning `'A'` worked previously because this is a normal character literal and has type `char`. `std::string` has an overload of `operator=` that takes a `char`.