# C++ outputs numbers instead string

Tags: c++

I'm new in C++, and I try to print 'Hello world'.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << 'Hello world!';
    return 0;
}
```

But in result I got '1919706145'. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For more information on single and double quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters

Comment: It's a very good idea to enable compiler warnings. That should at least tell you that something's not right here, although it might be difficult to figure out what it means at first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strings are represented by ", not '

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!"; // Use " not '
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used to use both type of quotes)

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
```

Use ' ' for characters not strings.
Characters are single alphabets like 'h', 'i', etc while string is "hi".

Answer (score 2):

Try doing :

```
cout << "Hello world!"; // <---------Double Quotes
```

Strings use double quotes. Single quotes are for single characters.