# How does C++ understand two letter characters

Tags: c++

C++ seems to allow up to four characters to be held in single quotes, such as:

```
char c = 'abcd';
```

but at runtime, only the last value ('d') seems to be actually stored away. This behavior seems to happen for pairs of two, three, or four (at five the compiler finally calls uncle). But what's the deal with this design? I don't really see the logic in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal

Comment: [Multicharacter literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)

Comment: Usually g++, but for this example I just used VC++

Comment: The reason you only get `d` is because you're converting the `int` value of the literal to `char`, discarding all but one byte of it. (Note that it's implementation-defined; on other platforms, you might get `a`, or something else entirely).

Comment: @MikeSeymour:  Is it really implementation defined, or Undefined?

Comment: @JohnDibling Both the value of the literal, and the result of signed overflow when converting to a smaller integer type, are implementation-defined. (It's also implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or not; if not, then the conversion result is defined).