# Single quoted string to uint in c#

Tags: c#, c++, string

I was translating some C++ to C# code and I saw the below definiton:

```
#define x 'liaM'
```

First, what does this single quoted constant mean? Do I make it a string constant in c#?

Second, this constant is assigned as value to a uint variable in C++. How does that work?

```
uint m = x;
```

Comment: Since your question is predominantly about the meaning of some C++ code, I'd have added that language tag as well as the C# one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is sometimes called a [FOURCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC). There's a Windows API that can convert from a string into a FOURCC called [mmioStringToFOURCC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and here's some C# code to do the same thing:

```
public static int ChunkIdentifierToInt32(string s)
{
    if (s.Length != 4) throw new ArgumentException("Must be a four character string");
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    if (bytes.Length != 4) throw new ArgumentException("Must encode to exactly four bytes");
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
}
```

Comment: Why not just `BitConverter.ToInt32(char[] { 'l', 'i', 'a', 'M' });`  and skip the string entirely?

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, even better. I wrote the code above as a drop-in replacement for calls to mmioStringToFOURCC

Comment: Actually, my comment should have used `byte[]`