# Print Char Array in C - only last letter?

Tags: c

```
int main (){

    char array[2] = {'hola', 'adios'};  
    int i = 0;

    while (i<3){
        printf("%c", array[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't why the output is the final letter of each word, like this: as:)

And it appears a smiley face, wtf?

I simply want to output hola adios

Comment: thats not a char array, that's a string array where u need to enclose `hola` in double quotes ( "hola" )

Comment: if i use double quotes: excess elements in char array initializer

Comment: u need to change declaration part as well like this `char* array[2] ={ "hola", "adios"};`

Comment: Enable all warnings in your compiler (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g`). It would have warned you....

Comment: Also: change `while (i<3)` to `while (i<2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need strings, not chars. `hola` is a string, not a `char`. Strings are surrounded in `""` not in `''`. So you need

```
const char* array[2] = { "hola", "adios" };
```

Now, this array has 2 elements, so loop through them

```
while (i<2){ /* also NOTE: 2 elements in the array */
    printf("%s", array[i]); /* note the "%s", it's not "%c" */
    i++;
}
```

I'd use `for` loop instead.

Why you don't have a compile-time error? See [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters) - it's similar in `C`.

Comment: +1 Had to think twice about the need for `const`, which I am certain is best.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating array of 2 **single char** elements. Declare array of two strings, and use double-quotes to declare strings, and not chars:

```
char* array[2] = {"hola", "adios"};
```

Also, in `printf`, use `%s` for printing out strings. And `i` should be in range `{0, 1}` - don't include `2`.

Comment: It's not invalid syntax, it's a multicharacter literal.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters

Comment: @NemanjaBoric - I've reverted my down-vote, as I'm not 100% sure it's valid in C (I didn't mention it's not about C++).

Comment: @KirilKirov - don't worry - I didn't know if it is valid in the C++ - nice thing to learn today!

Comment: @KirilKirov, It's still there in C, it's just grouped together with a single character one as an *integer character constant*, as opposed to actually being named a *multicharacter literal* in C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
char array[2] = {'hola', 'adios'};
```

This is not valid. You are in the Undefined Behavior zone.

You need a `char**` or `char[] []` and use `""` instead of `''` for your strings.

Comment: What's undefined here? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters

Comment: @KirilKirov Character literals are valid in C++. This question is about C.

Comment: Point taken, I've reverted my down-vote, as I'm not 100% sure it's valid in C.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, From the C99 standard: *An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed
in single-quotes*. Anyway, I think the implementation-defined value of the constant being converted to a `char` could potentially be UB that would most likely just wrap.