# Why is the output of following code comes 25448?

Tags: c++, output

When I try to run this code, it gives the following output:

```
c
99
25448
4636795
```

I want to know how the compiler generates the last two output?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char ch='c';

    printf("%c\n",ch);
    printf("%d\n",ch);
    printf("%d\n",'ch');
    printf("%d","ch");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'ch'` ends up being two bytes (`'c' << 8 | 'h'`) and `"ch"` is a pointer and you're telling it to print an integer value.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Please elaborate sir.

Comment: I recommend you pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++ and use [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) as a general reference.

Comment: Most books don't cover multibyte `char` literals!

Answer (score 6):

```
printf("%c",ch);       - print normal character
printf("%d\n",ch);     - print ascii value of character
printf("%d\n",'ch');   - multi-character literal
printf("%d","ch");     - print value of pointer to string "ch"
```

Regarding 'ch'

25448 is `0x6368` and 63 is hex for 'c' and 68 is hex for 'h'

Comment: what is wchar_t wide character?

Comment: No,  `'ch'` is a multibyte character constant,  **not** wchar_t

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc can you explain the output of last two lines sir. I am new to programming

Comment: +1 / Just quoting the Standard showing 'ch' will be passed as `int` in C++, so the `%d` format's definitely appropriate "An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a *multicharacter literal*. A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the execution character set, is conditionally-supported, has type `int`, and has an implementation-defined value.".  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%c", ch);     // print ch as a character
printf("%d\n", ch);   // print the ASCII value of ch
printf("%d\n", 'ch'); // print the value of the multi-character literal 'ch'
                      // implementation defined, but in this case 'ch' == 'c' << 8 | 'h'
printf("%d", "ch");   // print the address of the string literal "ch"
                      // undefined behavior, read below
```

About multi-character literal read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7459939/995714)

Your code [invokes *undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714) in the last `printf`, since you're using the wrong format specifier. `printf` is expecting an integer and you're passing an address. In 64-bit system this is most probably a 64-bit value while `int` is 32 bits. The correct version should be

```
printf("%p", (void*)"ch");
```

Another problem is that you didn't use anything in `iostream`, why include it? Don't include both `iostream` and `stdio.h`. Prefer `iostream` in C++ because it's safer. If needed, use `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h`

And you shouldn't tag both C and C++. They're different languages