# Behaviour of char variables, what values are assigned and why?

Tags: c, gcc, char, output

I was practicing some *C* related MCQ's and I came across a question to predict output. Here's the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a = '012';
    char b = '\012';
    printf("%d %d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The Output given was: `50 10`

Then I added following more lines and executed on *gcc compiler*

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char a = '\012';
    char b = '\08';
    char c = '012';
    char d = '\0x12';
    printf("%d %d %d %d", a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output I got was `10 56 50 50`  (See [this](http://ideone.com/dDbGbm))

For some variables I think the *ASCII* of last char is assigned but not for all. Can anyone explain this behavior and How values are assigned ? And it would be helpful if anyone can quote references for these.

Comment: Read about [multicharacter litera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)

Comment: @unwind How is this duplicate to the one you marked, that was about multichar char scope and uses. The one *Mohit Jain* quoted is more appropriate.
Besides I want to know that if they are multichar why sometimes *ASCII* of last char is assigned and sometimes some other value.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia I disagree. The point is that the behavior of multichar literals is implementation-defined.