# Trying to make block collision for c++ cmd game so that platforms are solid, but wont work

Tags: c++, game-physics

Im working on a cmd game for fun and I've run into a problem.  I've coded in the movement and gravity, but in my last if statement where I attempt to make the character seize his downward movement if above a '219' char or in other wards a block, it doesnt work.  I end up still going right through the block and deleting it if I attempt to fall on it.  Heres the full source code so you may run it and see what I mean.

```
using namespace std;
```

`char Map[10][81] =
{

   "                                                                                ",
   "                                                                                ",
   "                                                                                ",
   "                                                                                ",
   "                                                   ###                          ",
   "                                                                                ",
   "                                                                                ",
   "                                                                                ",
   "                                                                                ",
   "################################################################################",
};

int main()
{
bool start = true;
char dood('0');
bool print(false);

int x = 1;
int y = 8;

Map [y][x] = dood;
int cnt = 0;
int Height = 0;
int space_below = Map [y + 1][x];

while(start = true)
{

    Sleep(20);
    system("cls");


    for(auto &c: Map)
    {
        for(auto &d: c)
        {
                if(d == '#')
                {
                    d = 219;
                }
                cout << d;
        }
        cout << endl;

    }
    cout << "Height: " << Height <<" units";



    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
        {
            if(x != 79)
            {
            Map [y][x] = ' ';
            x++;
            Map [y][x] = dood;
            }
        }
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
            {
                if(x != 0)
                {
                Map [y][x] = ' ';
                x--;
                Map [y][x] = dood;
                }
            }


    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
    {
        if(y < 9 && y > 0)
        {
            Map[y][x] = ' ';
            y--;
            Height++;
            Map[y][x] = dood;
        }
    }

    if(y < 8 && !GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
        {
            if(space_below  != '219')
            {
                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                y++;
                Height--;
                Map[y][x] = dood;
            }
        }
}
return 0;
}`

*Note: Inlude statements would work when pasting them in here, but I included iostream, windows.h, and time.h.

The last if statement is my gravity which procs if the player is not holding up, and when space_below, or the block below him is not a '219' ascii character, but but for some reason when I try to jump on that platform I made this doesn't work and that character just falls through and turns the block into a space(deletes it)!

I'm kinda new to c++, so I understand my mistake could be stupidly simple, but I haven't been able to find a fix on the internet.  Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You don't re-calculate space_below.  Just put "space_below = Map [y + 1][x];" right before your check "if(space_below  != 219)"

Comment: I changed that as well and it yielded the same result, character still falls through the platform

Comment: beside what @choeger and Michael said, did you forget your Map does not contains any 219, but sharp (#) characters ? The numeric code (ansi) of # is 35, not 219. Just print what you get in the loop at Map[y+1][x] and it should be obvious.

Comment: That changed that as well but that doesn't work either, the character is still falling through the platform.  Is there an alternate way to make this block collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple : You are comparing the literal `'219'` to the number `219`, which are not the same thing. The tokens are actually completely different values. It is a coincidence that the compiler did not report a type error.

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters) for more details on what a single quote string actually is (I didn't know that myself).

Comment: I see what you mean, and I changed the comparison in my last if statement to space_below != 219.  I also changed space below to a char after I saw that didnt work and I still have the same issue with the character falling through the platform.