# Does C++ allow 8 byte long multi-character literals?

Tags: c++, character, literals

Why is this allowed:

```
uint32_t x = 'name';
```

But this gets truncated to 32 bits:

```
uint64_t x = 'namename';
```

Is there a way to have an 8-byte long multicharacter literal?

Comment: I don't recognize this kind of syntax. how could you compile a string with character syntax?

Comment: It compiles correctly, but I don't see the use case of this code!

Comment: @DavidHaim: `'name'` is not a string literal, it's a character literal, specifically a *multicharacter literal*. It's of type `int` and has an implementation-defined value. It's not a particularly useful language feature.

Comment: [C++ multicharacter literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3960954/995714), [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7459939/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as long as your compiler has 8-byte `int`s and supports it.

The C++ standard is farily terse regarding multi-character literals. This is all it has to say on the matter (C++14, 2.14.3/1):

> An
>   ordinary character literal that contains more than one *c-char* is a *multicharacter literal.* A multicharacter
>   literal, or an ordinary character literal containing a single *c-char* not representable in the execution character
>   set, is conditionally-supported, **has type `int`**, and has an implementation-defined value.

(Emphasis mine)

As you see, pretty much all the standard says is that if multicharacter literals are supported (they don't have to be), they are of type `int`. The value is up to the compiler.

Comment: So the short answer is that it works this way because int is 32 bits on his platform.

Comment: Why one would like to initialize an integer to a string literal? could you give some examples?

Comment: @redobot: string literals can't be used as template arguments, multichar literals can be abused as "short string template arguments" (not that I'd recommend that beyond toys)

Comment: @redobot: `'name'` is not a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

If only 4 byte multi-character literats are supported, you could use:

```
uint64_t x = (((uint64_t)'abcd') << 32) + 'efgh';
```

but it would probably end up as 2 literals.