# Explanation of this code output

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

```
int i = 0, j = 6;
while (j>3)
  cout << j-- << ': ' << ++i << endl;
```

Output: I do not understand the numbers in between 6 and 1 in the first output line of code for example.

```
6148801
5148802
4148803
```

Comment: The output does not correspond to the code i.e. ':' does not appear in it!

Comment: You need to enable more compiler warnings.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you used ' for the string containing the colon, hence the characters are interpreted as chars, not as a string. Use ": " instead of ': '.

Comment: This is an exam question, therefore I need an understanding not a correction of the code

Answer (score 1):

`14880` is ': '

change ': ' to ": "

Comment: why is ': ' equal to 14880

Comment: Check the ASCII table its their values one followed by other.