# Different answers with single and double quotes while displaying in C++

Tags: c++

I have displayed a statement in C++ program with single quote and answer which i got was the random numbers where as when i used the double quotes in C++ it displayed me the statement.

```
cout << 'Hello world'; //gave me the random numbers
cout << "Hello world"; //displayed me the statement i.e Hello world
```

Why This happened pls do let me know and what those random numbers were at the time of execution ?

Comment: ' are for characters , single ones,, use the "" please for strings, the random stuff you were seeing with the ' are a memory dump of your machine starting from that character up to the first \0

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960954/c-multicharacter-literal

Comment: It's a multicharacter literal, check this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are used for characters:
`char c = 'A';`

In case you want to print a string which is more than one character, you use double quotes: 
`cout << "Hello World";`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print an array of characters, which require double quotes.

```
char str[3] = "abc"; //an array of characters, use double quotes
str[0] = 'x';   //set a character in this array, use single quote
```