# function SpacePlug takes a pointer to string and a another char as arguments.

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
void SpacePlug(char *StringPtr, char Ch)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*(StringPtr + i)!= '\0')
    {
        if (*(StringPtr + i)== ' ')
        {
            *(StringPtr + i ) = '^^';
            printf("%c",*(StringPtr + i));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    char a[]= "Alton Tait";
    SpacePlug(a,);
}
```

Function is to replace each space in the string with the character .In main, use SpacePlug 
i want to replace the space between alton tait with ^^ so it should be alton^^tait
thats what i come up with i cant i would like to know where i went wrong. thank you

Comment: This looks like C (with a syntax error). Why did you add the C++ tag?

Comment: Because i would accept help from anyone.

Comment: Tags are not to attract maximum attention, but sort questions! Please follow site rules, read [ask]. C and C++ are **different** languages.

Answer (score 0):

`'^^'` is not a character. It is a multi-character constant, [which is not portable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7459939/335858).

Your code is good for a single-character replacements, i.e.

```
SpacePlug(a, '^');
```

You also need to move printing out of the `if`:

```
int i = 0;
while (*(StringPtr + i)!= '\0')
{
    if (*(StringPtr + i)== ' ')
    {
        *(StringPtr + i ) = '^';
    }
    printf("%c", *(StringPtr + i));
    i++;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/IqkFtN)

To make replacements for multiple characters you need an entirely different approach:

- Pass `char*` for the replacement
- Make sure the string has enough space to expand for the extra characters
- Do the replacement in two passes
- Compute the total length after replacement in the first pass
- Starting from the back, perform replacements as you go, using the same space.

Comment: Sorry about the double character '^^' i only need it to replace with one thank for your help really appreciate .

Comment: wheneve i run it, its only printing out ^ its not printing out Alton^tait.

Answer (score 0):

This is the output i get when i try to compile your code using gcc:

```
In function 'SpacePlug':
8:33: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
             *(StringPtr + i ) = '^^';
                                 ^
8:33: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 In function 'main':
17:17: error: expected expression before ')' token
     SpacePlug(a,);
```

you should hace included the error report in the question, so it's easier to see what's going on.

You've got a few problems on your code:

- "^^" is not a character, but a string with 2 characters. '^' is a character. That's the reason for the "multi-charater" error
- You're not using "Ch" inside SpacePlug. The replacing character is hardcoded. I'ts always '^^', which doesn't exist.
- The function is not properly called in main. It's missing a parameter.

Now for the solution. What i understood is that "SpacePlug" tries to find all spaces inside a string, the first parameter, and replace them with a character, which is the second parameter. The following code will work just fine for that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void SpacePlug(char *StringPtr, char Ch, char *newString)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(StringPtr); i++)
    {
        if (StringPtr[i] == ' ')
        {
            newString[i] = Ch;
        }
        else
        {
            newString[i] = StringPtr[i];
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char *a = "Alton Tait";
    char replace = '^';
    char *newString = (char *)malloc(strlen(a) + 1); // the +1 is for the null terminator
    SpacePlug(a, replace, newString);
    printf("%s\n", newString);

    free(newString);
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the code is not compiling.

Comment: This code fails to NULL terminate `newString`. The allocation also needs to be larger to account for the NULL.

Comment: There, i edited it so a new string is taken as a parameter instead of creating it inside function. I initialize the memory space and then destroy it before leaving. Hope it compiles this time.