# Format json code into std::string

Tags: c++, json

It's a beginner question,
how would I format the following json array of strings into std::string

```
[
  { 
    "x" : 12.1,
    "y" : 12.1,
    "z" : 12.1
  },
  { 
    "x" : 12.1,
    "y" : 12.1,
    "z" : 12.1
  },  
  { 
    "x" : 12.1,
    "y" : 12.1,
    "z" : 12.1
  },  
  { 
    "x" : 12.1,
    "y" : 12.1,
    "z" : 12.1
  }
]
```

Here is the json string

```
const std::string json =
            "[\n"
            "  {\n"
            "    \"x\" : 0,\n"
            "    \"y\" : 0,\n"
            "    \"z\" : 0\n"
            "  },\n"
            "  {\n"
            "    \"x\" : 640,\n"
            "    \"y\" : 0,\n"
            "    \"z\" : 0\n"
            "  },\n"
            "  {\n"
            "    \"x\" : 640,\n"
            "    \"y\" : 0,\n"
            "    \"z\" : 480\n"
            "  },\n"
            "  {\n"
            "    \"x\" : 0,\n"
            "    \"y\" : 0,\n"
            "    \"z\" : 480\n"
            "  }\n"
            "]\n";


        Json::Value coordinates;
        Json::Reader reader;

        reader.parse( json, coordinates );
```

So I'm trying to parse the above json array, to get a list of coordinates, but it can't be parsed correctly.

Comment: Json *is* a string. It's not code. `"[{"x:12.1},{"x":12.1"}]"` is a Json string. What do you mean? Are you trying to create a

Comment: my question how to write that json into std::string

Comment: Just like any other string. Json is a string, whose contents have a specific format. Nothing more.

Comment: what about the x, how would I make it work should I put +"\x"+

Comment: You are asking how to insert *quotes* and *double quotes* into a string. This has nothing to do with Json. The easiest solution is to use `'` instead of `"`. It's still valid JSON. Otherwise, you need to escape any special characters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _“The easiest solution is to use `'` instead of `"`”._ Not in C++. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters

Comment: @Melebius what you link to has nothing to do with string **contents**. You can have a string that contains single quotes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So you meant inside the JSON? I understood you advised to put single quotes around it, like you could do in PHP, Python or shell, for example.

Comment: Which is the error message ?

Comment: @Melebius `You are asking how to insert quotes and double quotes into a string ... ` This is a question about Json, where it's very common to use single instead of double quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use raw string since C++11:

```
const std::string json = R"(
[
  { 
    "x" : 12.1,
    "y" : 12.1,
    "z" : 12.1
  },
  { 
    "x" : 12.1,
    "y" : 12.1,
    "z" : 12.1
  },  
  { 
    "x" : 12.1,
    "y" : 12.1,
    "z" : 12.1
  },  
  { 
    "x" : 12.1,
    "y" : 12.1,
    "z" : 12.1
  }
]
)";
```

before, you have to do some escaping as `"` -> `\"`:

```
const std::string json = 
"[\n"
"  {\n"
"    \"x\" : 12.1,\n"
"    \"y\" : 12.1,\n"
"    \"z\" : 12.1\n"
"  },\n"
"  {\n"
"    \"x\" : 12.1,\n"
"    \"y\" : 12.1,\n"
"    \"z\" : 12.1\n"
"  },\n" 
"  {\n"
"    \"x\" : 12.1,\n"
"    \"y\" : 12.1,\n"
"    \"z\" : 12.1\n"
"  },\n"
"  {\n"
"    \"x\" : 12.1,\n"
"    \"y\" : 12.1,\n"
"    \"z\" : 12.1\n"
"  }\n"
"]\n";
```

Comment: Also before he had to escape `\n`. For completeness: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal see: `prefix(optional) R "delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter"  (6)  (since C++11)`.

Comment: Can you write it without the Raw, just for a complete answer

Comment: There is no need to use newlines. Whitespace is ignored in Json. Instead of `"` one can also use `'` and avoid escaping altogether

Comment: Unfortuantely, the Raw macro, doesn't work with Json reader
  
       Json::Value coordinates;
        Json::Reader reader;
 
        reader.parse( jsonstring, coordinates );

Comment: @andre post *actual* code that reproduces your problem and include the full error message. It may be that you used invalid tags, or that a required tag is missing. Or it could be a quirk of the parser library. What is `Json::Reader` ?

Comment: @andre not yet. What is `Json::Reader` ? What is the error message? C++ doesn't have any Json support and the string is OK as it is.