# Multiple characters in single quotes

Tags: c

```
char a;
a='hii';
printf("%c",a);
```

I expect the output of printf("%c",a) to be h, but the actual output is i
how?

Comment: Implementation defined behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters