# C++ comparing a char to a string literal

Tags: c++, char, compare

Beginning programmer here...

I'm writing a very simply program for my computer science class and I ran into an issue that I'd like to know more about. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char courseLevel;

    cout << "Will you be taking graduate or undergraduate level courses (enter 'U'"
            " for undergraduate,'G' for graduate.";
    cin >> courseLevel;

    if (courseLevel == "U")
    {
        cout << "You selected undergraduate level courses.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting two error messages for my if statement:
1) Result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead).
2) Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char*').

I seem to have resolved the issue by enclosing my U in single quotes, or the program at least works anyway. But, as I stated, I'd simply like to understand why I was getting the error so I can get a better understanding of what I'm doing.

Comment: Use single quotes instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use single quotes instead.

In C, (and many other languages) a [**character constant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Character_constants) is a *single* character<sup>1</sup> contained in single quotes:

```
'U'
```

While a [**string literal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Strings) is any number of characters contained in double quotes:

```
"U"
```

You declared `courseLevel` as a single character: `char courseLevel;` So you can only compare that to another single `char`.

When you do `if (courseLevel == "U")`, the left side is a `char`, while the right side is a `const char*` -- a *pointer*  to the first `char` in that string literal. Your compiler is telling you this:

> Comparison between pointer and integer ('`int`' and '`const char*`')

---

So your options are:

```
if (courseLevel == 'U')       // compare char to char
```

Or, for sake of example:

```
if (courseLevel == "U"[0])    // compare char to first char in string
```

---

1. Note for completeness: You *can* have [mulit-character constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699301/is-int-x-fooo-a-compiler-extension):

   int a = 'abcd';  // 0x61626364 in GCC

But this is certainly not what you're looking for.

Comment: Ahh, that's simple enough. Makes sense. I didn't realize that enclosing something in quotes denotes a string and enclosing it in single quotes denotes a char. That's the explanation I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Being pedantic, `'abcd'` is not a multi-byte character constant. It's a **multicharacter literal**. `L'a'` is a multi-byte character constant; it represents a multi-byte character whose type is `wchar_t`.

Comment: GCC calls it a "multi-character constant", which I changed it to.

Answer (score 3):

Rapptz is right, but I think some more elaboration should help...

```
courseLevel == "U"
```

In C and C++, double-quotes create *string literals* - which are arrays of characters finishing with a numerical-0 ASCII-NUL terminating sentinel character so programs can work out where the text ends.  So, you basically are asking if a character is equal to an array of characters... they just can't be compared.  Similar questions that are valid are:

- does this character variable hold a specific character value:  `courseLevel == 'U'`
- does this character variable appear in a specific array:  `strchr(courseLevel, "U")`
- does this character variable match the first element in a specific array:  `courseLevel == "U"[0]`

Of course, the first one of these is the one that makes intuitive sense in your program.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get an error is because string literals in C and C++ end with a null terminated character `\0` while single characters don't. So when you compare to a `char` to a string literal you're comparing the character literal to a char array `{'U','\0'}`.

Comment: If you say so. Sorry I guess.

Comment: +1 this is relevant background

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I really don't know what to edit, sorry :(

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: "for argument's sake that we're dealing with DOS strings which are $ terminated" - not relevant as the question is clearly about C string literals, which are always NUL terminated - Rapptz has even restated that context in his answer.  (And strictly speaking he's not comparing "a pointer to that array"... an array-to-pointer conversion would be attempted in resolving the comparison (and failed) but the rhs type is definitely array-of-char.)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: that's still not correct though... consider that in C++ `template <size_t N> void f(const char (&)[N]) { ... }` can be called with a character array - that's an example of a function argument where an array isn't passed by pointer.  Similarly, an `operator==` for a user defined type doesn't have to rely on the array-to-pointer standard conversion.  Anyway, I'm not going to argue about it further - I've read that part of the Standard carefully many times, if you care you'll do so too.

Comment: @TonyD Why then is the compiler giving him a warning `Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char*')` ?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: probably because it's the last Standard Conversion that particular compiler attempted before it failed, and it (poorly) issued an error about that last-ditch attempt rather than the underlying comparison.

Comment: Fair enough - but then how does one compare two "array-of-chars"? Certainly they are compared by their addresses (ie. as pointers). In a (C) test program, I just confirmed that (because of string interning) `"foo"=="foo"`, but of course, `"foo"!="foo\0"`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: yes, the only conversion that works for two arrays is to compare after that Standard Conversion to pointers. As per C++11 2.14.5/12, "foo" may legally compare equal to "foo\0", as the compiler is allowed to find a suitable substring within another literal... similarly "afoo"+1 == "foo" may be true on some compilers. Same in C++03 (and C from memory).