# Why does this code with '1234' compile in C++?

Tags: c++, char

Why does this compile:

```
char ch = '1234'; //no error
```

But not anything more than 4 `char`s :

```
char ch = '12345'; //error: Too many chars in constant
```

(Yes I know `' '` is used for one `char` and `" "` is for strings; I was just experimenting)

Does this have anything to do with the fact that `char`s are represented using ASCII numbers?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7755202/335858

Comment: What made you think that it shouldn't?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)

Comment: @AndreyT I didn't know about multi-character literals and thought the compiler will reject more than one char in single quotation.

Comment: There's no reason at all to use multi-character literals in C++11 because you can just write your own UDL.

Comment: There is no requirement that `char`s use ASCII numbers. Most platforms use ASCII, but there are other character encodings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a multicharacter literal, and has a type of `int`.

> #### C++11 §2.13.2 Character literals
>
> A character literal is one or more characters enclosed in single quotes, as in `’x’`, optionally preceded by the letter `L`, as in `L’x’`. A character literal that does not begin with `L` is an ordinary character literal, also referred to as a narrow-character literal. An ordinary character literal that contains a single c-char has type char, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the c-char in the execution character set. **An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal has type `int` and implementation-defined value.**

Comment: @soandos The digits are treated as normal characters `'1'`, `'2'`, etc. According to the standard, it has implementation-defined value, but normally the value is as @Steve Jessop says in his answer.

Comment: The second part of the question: why is it an error at 5 or more characters?  Is that implementation defined?

Comment: @Yakk I think so. It's likely that 5 or more characters would hold a value bigger than a 32-bit `int`, and I tested under GCC, it's a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 17):

C++ has something called "multicharacter literals". `'1234'` is an example of one. They have type `int`, and it is implementation-defined what value they have and how many characters they can contain.

It's nothing *directly* to do with the fact that characters are represented as integers, but chances are good that in your implementation the value of `'1234'` is defined to be either:

```
'1' + 256 * '2' + 256 * 256 * '3' + 256 * 256 * 256 * '4'
```

or:

```
'4' + 256 * '3' + 256 * 256 * '2' + 256 * 256 * 256 * '1'
```

Comment: it should be easier to understand by using shift operator or power notation

Comment: is it really defined to be one of those two?  I thought it was unspecified completely.

Comment: @Yakk. It is implementation-defined, not unspecified. "Chances are good" means that those are the two likely choices that the implementation would have made.

Comment: The second version holds for me.