# return value of sizeof() operator in C & C++

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d", sizeof('a'));
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the above code produce different results when compiling in C and C++ ?
In C, it prints 4 while in C++, it is the more acceptable answer i.e. 1.
When I replace the 'a' inside sizeof() with a char variable declared in main function, the result is 1 in both cases!

Comment: What makes `1` a more acceptable answer than `4`?

Comment: @Paddyd Because `sizeof(char)` is `1` in both C and C++ ?

Comment: @Paddyd because of what the size of a char is! This difference was not known to me, and so 1 was obvious

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because, and this might be shocking, C and C++ are *not the same language*.

C defines character literals as having type `int`, while C++ considers them to have type `char`.

This is a case where multi-character constants can be useful:

```
const int foo = 'foo';
```

That will generate an integer whose value will probably be 6713199 or 7303014 depending on the byte-ordering and the compiler's mood. In other words, multiple-character character literals are not "portable", you cannot depend on the resulting value being easy to predict.

As commenters have pointed out (thanks!) this is valid in both C and C++, it seems C++ makes multi-character character literals a different type. Clever!

Also, as a minor note that I like to mention when on topic, note that `sizeof` is not a function and that values of `size_t` are not `int`. Thus:

```
printf("the size of a character is %zu\n", sizeof 'a');
```

or, if your compiler is too old not to support C99:

```
printf("the size of a character is %lu\n", (unsigned long) sizeof 'a');
```

represent the simplest and most correct way to print the sizes you're investigating.

Comment: [Multicharacter literals are legal in C++ as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19394141/1009479)

Comment: C++ also has multi-character literals, with type `int` and implementation-defined value.

Comment: why do I get `warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format` while using `%zu`?

Comment: +1 For highlighting that compilers are moody :-)

Comment: @noufal, AFAIK %zu appeared in C99. So you should add -std=c99 if you are using GCC compiler.

Comment: @noufal The safest code (runs on C89/90, which is what you're stuck with in Visual Studio, so far) is `printf("%u", (unsigned)(sizeof 'a'));`.  %d and (int) work too, since all built-in types will have small positive sizes.

Comment: @mjs: They certianly are; but in this case, it's implementation-defined (not undefined or unspecified), so the compiler should document what it does, and do that whatever its mood.

Comment: @MikeHousky I'm using `gcc version 4.7.1`.

Comment: @noufal I didn't say you weren't, but sometimes it's nice for code to port to other compilers.  I mentioned VC++ as an example of a widely-used but problematical compiler (in C mode...the C++ is okay.)

Answer (score 2):

In C, the 'a' is a character constant, which is treated as an integer, so you get a size of 4, whereas in C++ it's treated as a char.

possible duplicate question [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

You example is one of the cases where C++ is not compatible with C. In C APIs that return a single character (like `getch`) return and `int` because this allows space for an EOF marker (-1). So for this reason it sees 'c' as an int.

C++ introduces operator and function overloading which means that we probably want to handle

```
cout << 'c'
```

differently to:

```
cout << 99
```