# How to if user input matches a specific value?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple c++ measurement program that asks the user input to select from which unit they would like to measure the unit from and to the unit? but I don't know if the structure is correct (my C++ really sucks). Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int storeFROM, storeTO;
    char mm, cm, m, kk;

    cout << "Enter the initial unit (mm, cm, m, or km): ";
    cin >> storeFROM;

    cout << endl;

    if ((storeFROM != 'mm') || storeFROM != 'cm' || storeFROM != 'm' || storeFROM != 'km') {
        cout << "--> Sorry unit to convert FROM is invalid" << endl;
    }
    else if ((storeFROM == 'mm') || storeFROM == 'cm' || storeFROM == 'm' || storeFROM == 'km') 
    {
        cout << "Enter the initial unit(mm, cm, m, or kk) :";
        cin >> storeTO;
    }

    // Calculate the selected units
    system("pause");
}
```

I hope someone can help me asking the user input to ask from which unit they want, this is exactly how it should show:

[image]

Comment: Some part of the last sentence is missing in the question.

Comment: yea i didn't add the metric calculations because I might know how to do that, it's just setting up the structure of how to ask the question, is the part that i am really bad at :(

Comment: Start by storing user input in the right datatypes. Right now you are trying to store `char`s and `strings`s in `int`s, and later on compare them to `char`s and `string`s again. Also you cant compare strings using `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the right code:

```
bool isValidUnit(const std::string &unit);
int convertValue(double value, const std::string &unitFrom, const std::string &unitTo);

int main() {

    ...

    std::string storeFROM, storeTO;

    cout << "Enter the initial unit (mm, cm, m, or km): ";
    cin >> storeFROM;

    if (!isValidUnit(storeFROM)) {
        cout << "--> Sorry unit to convert FROM is invalid" << endl;
        ...
    }

    cout << "Enter the initial unit (mm, cm, m, or km): ";
    cin >> storeTO;

    if (!isValidUnit(storeTO)) {
        cout << "--> Sorry unit to convert TO is invalid" << endl;
        ...
    }

    double value;

    cout << "Enter the value in (" << storeFROM << "): ";
    cin >> value;

    double valueConverted = convertValue(value, storeFROM, storeTO);

    cout << "Value in (" << storeTO << "): " << valueConverted << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool isValidUnit(const std::string &unit) {
    return unit == "mm" || unit == "cm" || unit == "m" || unit == "km";
}

double unitMultiplier(const std::string &unit) {
    if (unit == "mm") return 0.001;
    if (unit == "cm") return 0.01;
    if (unit == "m") return 1;
    if (unit == "km") return 1000;
    return 0.;
}

double convertValue(double value, const std::string &unitFrom, const std::string &unitTo) {
    if (unitFrom == unitTo) return value;
    if (value <= 0.) return 0.; // or value :)

    // Get it in meters
    int valueInMetes = value * unitMultiplier(unitFrom);
    return valuesInMeter / unitMultiplier(unitTo);
}
```

Comment: the !isValidUnit at the if statement is getting me an error, do I put this bool at the beginning before using isValidUnit at the if statement?

Comment: @PatrickGamboa, you should put this function (the whole function or its declaration) before you reference to it. Place it before main function

Comment: I got it working entirely, just editing some few codes, but the process worked! ok sorry to bother u but using my code, how do I use the units that the user inputed and do the specific unit conversion? hope you can help :)

Comment: I've updated the answer. Not sure it works right because didn't check it.

Comment: wow thank you! I've added them in, im just not sure about the conversion result if they are the right one, but I will get back to you! :D

Comment: hey! yea i did the conversion, for example i wanted to convert from km to mm and I added 56.12 km, the program actually convert the units to 5.612e+007, but the actual conversion is supposed to be 56123000.00 mm, i mixed up some conversion units, but I wasn't able to convert it to the proper units, any help here?

Comment: @PatrickGamboa, `5.612e+007 = 56120000` and this is the right result.

Comment: ah wait a sec the result gave me an exponential result, i added a cout.precision(9) to give more accurate result, thank you very much for your help! really appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 1):

In your program, `storeFROM` and `storeTO` are both `string`s, so you should declare them as `string`s:

```
string storeFROM, storeTO;
```

And when comparing them with values like `"cm"`, `"mm"`, etc, you should quote them in `""`, not `''` as you definitely don't want them to be [multicharacter literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19394188/2589776). It should look like this:

```
if ((storeFROM != "mm") || storeFROM != "cm" 
                        || storeFROM != "m" || storeFROM != "km") 
{
    cout << "--> Sorry unit to convert FROM is invalid" << endl;
}
else if ((storeFROM == "mm") || storeFROM == "cm" 
                             || storeFROM == "m" || storeFROM == "km") 
{
    cout << "Enter the initial unit(mm, cm, m, or kk) :";
    cin >> storeTO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string storeFROM, storeTO; // note string thingie
float value1, value2;

cin>>storeFROM;

if ((storeFROM != "mm") || storeFROM != "cm" || storeFROM != "m" || storeFROM != "km") )
{
    cout << "--> Sorry unit to convert FROM is invalid" << endl;
}
else  
{
    cin>>value1;
    cout << "Enter the initial unit(mm, cm, m, or kk) :";
    cin >> storeTO;
    if((storeTO == "mm") || storeTO == "cm" || storeTO == "m" || storeTO == "km"))
    {
       cin>>value2;
          //convert here...
          //hint: use switch-case
    }
}
//end programme
```

here...

Comment: What about strings and single quote usage?

Comment: `'mm'` will be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may not enter a non-acceptable symbols as for example letter 'm' for an object of type int.

You can use this code as a template for your program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

std::ostream & display_meazures( const std::initializer_list<const char *> &l,
                                 std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    auto it = l.begin();
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < l.size(); i++ )
    { 
        if ( i == l.size() - 1 ) os << "or ";
        os << *it;
        if ( i != l.size() - 1 ) os << ", ";
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
   std::string storeFROM, storeTO;

   std::initializer_list<const char *> meazure = { "mm", "cm", "m", "km" };

   while ( true )
   {
      std::cout << "Enter the initial unit (" << display_meazures( meazure ) 
                << "): ";
      std::cin >> storeFROM;

      if ( std::find( meazure.begin(), meazure.end(), storeFROM ) != 
           meazure.end() ) 
      {
        break;
      }

      std::cout << "--> Sorry unit to convert FROM is invalid" << std::endl;
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }

// Calculate the selected units

   std::system( "pause" );
}
```

Comment: Looks like an overkill. You can also use [user defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)